# How to assign columns while ignoring index alignment

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have two dataframes `x` and `y` in Pandas, I would like to fill in a column in `x` with the result of sorting a column in `y`. I tried this:

```
x['foo']  = y['bar'].order(ascending=False)
```

but it didn't work, I **suspect** because Pandas **aligns indices** between `x` and `y` (which have the same set of indices) during the assignment

How can I have Pandas fill in the `x['foo']`  with another column from another dataframe **ignoring** the alignment of indices?

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way I can think of to get `pandas` to ignore the indices is to give it something without indices to ignore.  Starting from

```
>>> x = pd.DataFrame({"foo": [10,20,30]},index=[1,2,0])
>>> y = pd.DataFrame({"bar": [33,11,22]},index=[0,1,2])
>>> x
   foo
1   10
2   20
0   30
>>> y
   bar
0   33
1   11
2   22
```

We have the usual aligned approach:

```
>>> x["foo"] = y["bar"].order(ascending=False)
>>> x
   foo
1   11
2   22
0   33
```

Or an unaligned one, by setting `x["foo"]` to a list:

```
>>> x["foo"] = y["bar"].order(ascending=False).tolist()
>>> x
   foo
1   33
2   22
0   11
```

Comment: I see, thanks. Would `my_series.tolist()` be better/worse than `np.array(my_series)` or `my_series.values()` ?

Comment: Except in some boundary cases I don't know if it would make much difference.  Come to think of it, `my_series.values` might be better at that, as it shouldn't have to go via a Python list, and so could be faster.  [Checks.. yeah, at least sometimes it's faster.]

Comment: What's the difference between `to_list` and `tolist`? I suspect they're the same, but how can I make sure?

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina Note that it's just `.values` without parentheses

Answer (score 2):

Simplest:

```
x['foo']  = y['bar'].sort_values(ascending=False).values
```

Adding `.values` at the end allows you to ignore indices

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code but it seems that the `order()` method has been deprecated, which is no surprise since the initial question is quite old. So now we are left with `sort_values()` to achieve the same result.
On top of that there's a refinement which consist in using `to_numpy()` since it is slightly faster and could be useful in case of big DataFrames (`.values` is even faster but it is recommended to use `to_numpy()` whenever working for production as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54324513/4909087)

```
>>> x["foo"] = y["bar"].sort_values(ascending=False)
>>> x
   foo
1   33
2   22
0   11

>>> %timeit x["foo"] = y["bar"].sort_values(ascending=False).to_list()
165 µs ± 965 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>> %timeit x["foo"] = y["bar"].sort_values(ascending=False).to_numpy()
136 µs ± 421 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>> %timeit x["foo"] = y["bar"].sort_values(ascending=False).values
129 µs ± 826 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```