# How do I convert a Pandas series or index to a NumPy array?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get the index or column of a DataFrame as a NumPy array or Python list?

Comment: Also, related: [Convert pandas dataframe to NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508052/4909087)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert pandas dataframe to NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array)

Comment: **NOTE:** Having to convert Pandas DataFrame to an array (or list) like this can be indicative of other issues. I strongly recommend ensuring that a DataFrame is the appropriate data structure for your particular use case, and that Pandas does not include any way of performing the operations you're interested in.

Comment: **Concerning my vote to reopen this question:** Technically, a pandas series is not the same as a pandas dataframe.
The answers may be the same, but the questions are definitely different.

Answer (score 380, accepted):

To get a NumPy array, you should use the `values` attribute:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]}, index=['a', 'b', 'c']); df
   A  B
a  1  4
b  2  5
c  3  6

In [2]: df.index.values
Out[2]: array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=object)
```

This accesses how the data is already stored, so there isn't any need for a conversion.

Note: This attribute is also available for many other pandas objects.

```
In [3]: df['A'].values
Out[3]: Out[16]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

---

To get the index as a list, call `tolist`:

```
In [4]: df.index.tolist()
Out[4]: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

And similarly, for columns.

Comment: Note: `.values` is deprecated, `.to_numpy()` is the suggested replacement if you want a NumPy array. Can you expand on _This accesses how the data is already stored, so there's no need for a conversion_?

Comment: The [answer by cs95](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54324513/11301900) gives a great explanation of `.values`, `.to_numpy()` and `.array`.

Answer (score 76):

You can use `df.index` to access the index object and then get the values in a list using `df.index.tolist()`. Similarly, you can use `df['col'].tolist()` for Series.

Comment: It returns instanceMethod and not a list array

Comment: @VShreyas ,how about `df.index.values.tolist()`

Comment: `df.index.tolist()` doesn't return an instance method. It returns a list of indices. It is a method defined on pandas index. While calling values first is a possibility, delegating the job to numpy is not a correction - just an alternative.

Answer (score 70):

### pandas >= 0.24

#### Deprecate your usage of `.values` in favour of these methods!

From v0.24.0 onwards, we will have two brand spanking new, preferred methods for obtaining NumPy arrays from `Index`, `Series`, and `DataFrame` objects: they are **`to_numpy()`**, and **`.array`**. Regarding usage, the docs mention:

> We haven’t removed or deprecated `Series.values` or
> `DataFrame.values`, but **we highly recommend and using `.array` or
> `.to_numpy()` instead.**

See [this section of the v0.24.0 release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#accessing-the-values-in-a-series-or-index) for more information.

---

**[`to_numpy()` Method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html)**

```
df.index.to_numpy()
# array(['a', 'b'], dtype=object)

df['A'].to_numpy()
#  array([1, 4])
```

By default, a view is returned. Any modifications made will affect the original.

```
v = df.index.to_numpy()
v[0] = -1
 
df
    A  B
-1  1  2
b   4  5
```

If you need a copy instead, use `to_numpy(copy=True`);

```
v = df.index.to_numpy(copy=True)
v[-1] = -123
 
df
   A  B
a  1  2
b  4  5
```

Note that this function also works for [DataFrames](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) (while `.array` does not).

---

**[`array` Attribute](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.array.html#pandas.Series.array)**
This attribute returns an [`ExtensionArray`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionArray.html) object that backs the Index/Series.

```
pd.__version__
# '0.24.0rc1'

# Setup.
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [4, 5]], columns=['A', 'B'], index=['a', 'b'])
df

   A  B
a  1  2
b  4  5
```

<!- ->

```
df.index.array    
# <PandasArray>
# ['a', 'b']
# Length: 2, dtype: object

df['A'].array
# <PandasArray>
# [1, 4]
# Length: 2, dtype: int64
```

From here, it is possible to get a list using `list`:

```
list(df.index.array)
# ['a', 'b']

list(df['A'].array)
# [1, 4]
```

or, just directly call `.tolist()`:

```
df.index.tolist()
# ['a', 'b']

df['A'].tolist()
# [1, 4]
```

Regarding what is returned, the docs mention,

> For `Series` and `Index`es backed by normal NumPy arrays, `Series.array`
> will return a new `arrays.PandasArray`, which is a thin (no-copy)
> wrapper around a `numpy.ndarray`. `arrays.PandasArray` isn’t especially
> useful on its own, but it does provide the same interface as any
> extension array defined in pandas or by a third-party library.

So, to summarise, `.array` will return either

1. The existing `ExtensionArray` backing the Index/Series, or
2. If there is a NumPy array backing the series, a new `ExtensionArray` object is created as a thin wrapper over the underlying array.

---

**Rationale for adding TWO new methods**
These functions were added as a result of discussions under two GitHub issues [GH19954](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19954) and [GH23623](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23623).

Specifically, the docs mention the rationale:

> [...] with `.values` it was unclear whether the returned value would be the
> actual array, some transformation of it, or one of pandas custom
> arrays (like `Categorical`). For example, with `PeriodIndex`, `.values`
> generates a new `ndarray` of period objects each time. [...]

These two functions aim to improve the consistency of the API, which is a major step in the right direction.

Lastly, `.values` will not be deprecated in the current version, but I expect this may happen at some point in the future, so I would urge users to migrate towards the newer API, as soon as you can.

Comment: `S = pd.Series( [3, 4] );  np.asarray( S ) is S.values` surprised me; would you know if this is documented anywhere ?  (numpy 1.21.5, pandas 1.3.5)

Answer (score 49):

If you are dealing with a multi-index dataframe, you may be interested in extracting only the column of one name of the multi-index. You can do this as

```
df.index.get_level_values('name_sub_index')
```

and of course `name_sub_index` must be an element of the `FrozenList` `df.index.names`

Answer (score 16):

Since pandas v0.13 you can also use [`get_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_values.html):

```
df.index.get_values()
```

Comment: Is there a difference between this and .values? (I updated version info, since this function appears from the 0.13.0 docs.)

Comment: @Andy Hayden: Isn't one difference that .get_values is the official way to get only the current values while .values (e.g. on a multi-index) may return index values for which the rows or columns have been deleted?

Comment: @EzekielKruglick so it's always a copy? The linked to documentation is very light, I didn't think you get dupes like that (even if they're in the MI they won't be in the .values) would be great to see an example which demonstrates this!

Comment: @AndyHayden: I think I was reading your comment wrong. You're right, .values is good, .level gives outdated and  get_values gives you the current values properly excluding dropped rows/cols. Original github issue: github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3686 But I just checked and it looks like .values (of course!) gives up to date info just in a different form than I thought was what we were talking about

Comment: @AndyHayden No, there is no difference. `get_values` just calls `.values`. It is more characters to type.

Answer (score 2):

A more recent way to do this is to use the .to_numpy() function.

If I have a dataframe with a column 'price', I can convert it as follows:

```
priceArray = df['price'].to_numpy()
```

You can also pass the data type, such as float or object, as an argument of the function

Answer (score 0):

I converted the pandas `dataframe` to `list` and then used the basic `list.index()`. Something like this:

```
dd = list(zone[0]) #Where zone[0] is some specific column of the table
idx = dd.index(filename[i])
```

You have you index value as `idx`.

Comment: _and then used the basic list.index()_ How is that related to the question of converting a Series to a list?

Answer (score -1):

Below is a simple way to convert a dataframe column into a NumPy array.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(somedict)
ytrain = df['label']
ytrain_numpy = np.array([x for x in ytrain['label']])
```

*ytrain_numpy* is a NumPy array.

I tried with `to.numpy()`, but it gave me the below error:

> TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),)* while doing Binary Relevance classfication using Linear SVC.

to.numpy() was converting the dataFrame into a NumPy array, but the inner element's data type was a list because of which the above error was observed.

Comment: _I tried with to.numpy() but it gave me the below error: TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),) while doing Binary Relevance classfication using Linear SVC. to.numpy() was converting the dataFrame into numpy array but the inner element's data type was list because of which the above error was observed._ That's not really the fault of `to_numpy`, though.