# Get a list from Pandas DataFrame column headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, header

I want to get a list of the column headers from a Pandas DataFrame.  The DataFrame will come from user input, so I won't know how many columns there will be or what they will be called.

For example, if I'm given a DataFrame like this:

```
    y  gdp  cap
0   1    2    5
1   2    3    9
2   8    7    2
3   3    4    7
4   6    7    7
5   4    8    3
6   8    2    8
7   9    9   10
8   6    6    4
9  10   10    7
```

I would get a list like this:

```
['y', 'gdp', 'cap']
```

Answer (score 2012, accepted):

You can get the values as a list by doing:

```
list(my_dataframe.columns.values)
```

Also you can simply use (as shown in [Ed Chum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19483602/4909087)):

```
list(my_dataframe)
```

Answer (score 518):

There is a built-in method which is the most performant:

```
my_dataframe.columns.values.tolist()
```

`.columns` returns an `Index`, `.columns.values` returns an array and this has a helper function `.tolist` to return a list.

If performance is not as important to you, `Index` objects define a `.tolist()` method that you can call directly:

```
my_dataframe.columns.tolist()
```

The difference in performance is obvious:

```
%timeit df.columns.tolist()
16.7 µs ± 317 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit df.columns.values.tolist()
1.24 µs ± 12.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

---

For those who hate typing, you can just call `list` on `df`, as so:

```
list(df)
```

Comment: That last option is very idiomatic, it makes reading code hard for me...

Answer (score 105):

I did some quick tests, and perhaps unsurprisingly the built-in version using `dataframe.columns.values.tolist()` is the fastest:

```
In [1]: %timeit [column for column in df]
1000 loops, best of 3: 81.6 µs per loop

In [2]: %timeit df.columns.values.tolist()
10000 loops, best of 3: 16.1 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit list(df)
10000 loops, best of 3: 44.9 µs per loop

In [4]: % timeit list(df.columns.values)
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.4 µs per loop
```

(I still really like the `list(dataframe)` though, so [thanks EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482970/get-a-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column-headers/19483602#19483602)!)

Answer (score 62):

## Extended Iterable Unpacking (Python 3.5+): `[*df]` and Friends

[Unpacking generalizations (PEP 448)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) have been introduced with Python 3.5. So, the following operations are all possible.

```
df = pd.DataFrame('x', columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=range(5))
df

   A  B  C
0  x  x  x
1  x  x  x
2  x  x  x
3  x  x  x
4  x  x  x
```

If you want a `list`....

```
[*df]
# ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Or, if you want a `set`,

```
{*df}
# {'A', 'B', 'C'}
```

Or, if you want a `tuple`,

```
*df,  # Please note the trailing comma
# ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

Or, if you want to store the result somewhere,

```
*cols, = df  # A wild comma appears, again
cols
# ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

... if you're the kind of person who converts coffee to typing sounds, well, this is going consume your coffee more efficiently ;)

> P.S.: if performance is important, you will want to ditch the
> solutions above in favour of
>
> ```
> df.columns.to_numpy().tolist()
> # ['A', 'B', 'C']
> ```
>
> This is similar to [Ed Chum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19483602/4909087), but updated for
> v0.24 where `.to_numpy()` is preferred to the use of `.values`. See
> [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54324513/4909087) (by me) for more information.

**Visual Check**

Since I've seen this discussed in other answers, you can use iterable unpacking (no need for explicit loops).

```
print(*df)
A B C

print(*df, sep='\n')
A
B
C
```

---

## Critique of Other Methods

Don't use an explicit `for` loop for an operation that can be done in a single line ([list comprehensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) are okay).

Next, using `sorted(df)` **does not preserve the original order** of the columns. For that, you should use `list(df)` instead.

Next, `list(df.columns)` and `list(df.columns.values)` are poor suggestions (as of the current version, v0.24). Both `Index` (returned from `df.columns`) and NumPy arrays (returned by `df.columns.values`) define `.tolist()` method which is faster and more idiomatic.

Lastly, listification i.e., `list(df)` should only be used as a concise alternative to the aforementioned methods for Python 3.4 or earlier where extended unpacking is not available.

Answer (score 61):

It gets even simpler (by Pandas 0.16.0):

```
df.columns.tolist()
```

will give you the column names in a nice list.

Answer (score 41):

```
>>> list(my_dataframe)
['y', 'gdp', 'cap']
```

To list the columns of a dataframe while in debugger mode, use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [c for c in my_dataframe]
['y', 'gdp', 'cap']
```

By the way, you can get a sorted list simply by using `sorted`:

```
>>> sorted(my_dataframe)
['cap', 'gdp', 'y']
```

Answer (score 26):

That's available as `my_dataframe.columns`.

Answer (score 21):

It's interesting, but `df.columns.values.tolist()` is almost three times faster than `df.columns.tolist()`, but I thought that they were the same:

```
In [97]: %timeit df.columns.values.tolist()
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.97 µs per loop

In [98]: %timeit df.columns.tolist()
10000 loops, best of 3: 9.67 µs per loop
```

Comment: Timings have already been covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27236748/4909087). The reason for the discrepancy is because `.values` returns the underlying numpy array, and doing something with numpy is almost always faster than doing the same thing with pandas directly.

Answer (score 19):

A [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#dataframe) follows the dict-like convention of iterating over the “keys” of the objects.

```
my_dataframe.keys()
```

Create a list of keys/columns - object method `to_list()` and the Pythonic way:

```
my_dataframe.keys().to_list()
list(my_dataframe.keys())
```

[Basic iteration](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#iteration) on a DataFrame returns column labels:

```
[column for column in my_dataframe]
```

Do not convert a DataFrame into a list, just to get the column labels. Do not stop thinking while looking for convenient code samples.

```py
xlarge = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100000000).reshape(10000,10000))
list(xlarge) # Compute time and memory consumption depend on dataframe size - O(N)
list(xlarge.keys()) # Constant time operation - O(1)
```

Answer (score 14):

### In the Notebook

For data exploration in the [IPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) notebook, my preferred way is this:

```
sorted(df)
```

Which will produce an easy to read alphabetically ordered list.

### In a code repository

In code I find it more explicit to do

```
df.columns
```

Because it tells others reading your code what you are doing.

Answer (score 11):

```
%%timeit
final_df.columns.values.tolist()
948 ns ± 19.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
list(final_df.columns)
14.2 µs ± 79.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
list(final_df.columns.values)
1.88 µs ± 11.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
final_df.columns.tolist()
12.3 µs ± 27.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
list(final_df.head(1).columns)
163 µs ± 20.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the summary and conclusion? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55701903/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 7):

Its very simple.

Like you can do it as:

list(df.columns)

Comment: Is this a new answer?

Answer (score 5):

The simplest option would be:
`list(my_dataframe.columns)` or `my_dataframe.columns.tolist()`

No need for the complex stuff above :)

Answer (score 3):

As [answered by Simeon Visser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482970/get-a-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column-headers/19483025#19483025), you could do

```
list(my_dataframe.columns.values)
```

or

```
list(my_dataframe) # For less typing.
```

But I think most the sweet spot is:

```
list(my_dataframe.columns)
```

It is explicit and at the same time not unnecessarily long.

Answer (score 3):

For a quick, neat, visual check, try this:

```
for col in df.columns:
    print col
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd

# create test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame('x', columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=range(2))

list(df.columns)
```

Returns

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel the question deserves an additional explanation.

As [fixxxer noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482970/get-a-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column-headers/29494537#29494537), the answer depends on the Pandas version you are using in your project. Which you can get with `pd.__version__` command.

If you are for some reason like me (on [Debian 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_8_(Jessie)) (Jessie) I use 0.14.1) using an older version of Pandas than 0.16.0, then you need to use:

`df.keys().tolist()` because there isn’t any `df.columns` method implemented yet.

The advantage of this keys method is that it works even in newer version of Pandas, so it's more universal.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = []
for i in my_dataframe.columns:
    n.append(i)
print n
```

Answer (score 1):

If the DataFrame happens to have an Index or MultiIndex and you want those included as column names too:

```
names = list(filter(None, df.index.names + df.columns.values.tolist()))
```

It avoids calling reset_index() which has an unnecessary performance hit for such a simple operation.

I've run into needing this more often because I'm shuttling data from databases where the dataframe index maps to a primary/unique key, but is really just another "column" to me. It would probably make sense for pandas to have a built-in method for something like this (totally possible I've missed it).

Answer (score 1):

**This is the easiest way to reach your goal.**

> my_dataframe.columns.values.tolist()

and if you are Lazy, try this >

> list(my_dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

its the simple code for you :

```
for i in my_dataframe:
    print(i)
```

just do it

Answer (score 0):

It's worth pointing out that there's almost no reason to convert the column headers into a list. `DataFrame.columns` will return an Index/MultiIndex object that can be indexed, sliced and appended similar to a list. In fact, since it's similar to a numpy array, you can index using a list (which you can't do with a list).

Some common tasks:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(5), 'B': range(6, 11), 'C': list('abcde')})

first_col_header = df.columns[0]                        # 1st column header
first_third_headers =  df.columns[[0,2]]                # 1st and 3rd column headers
df.columns = df.columns[:-1].append(pd.Index(['col5'])) # append a value
np.tile(df.columns, 2)      # == list(df)*2             # repeat headers
df.columns.repeat(2)        # == [c for c in df for _ in range(2)]
```

However, if you're here because you want to convert a values in a column into a list, then `tolist()` is your friend:

```py
lst = df['B'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas, then use the following

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'iris.csv')
#print(df.head(2))
# Dataframe show all columns
print(df.keys())
```

You can enable the commented `print(df.head(2))` to see headers and 2 rows of data.

Answer (score -1):

Even though the solution that was provided previously is nice, I would also expect something like frame.column_names() to be a function in Pandas, but since it is not, maybe it would be nice to use the following syntax. It somehow preserves the feeling that you are using pandas in a proper way by calling the "tolist" function: frame.columns.tolist()

```
frame.columns.tolist()
```

Answer (score -1):

listHeaders = [colName for colName in my_dataframe]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).