# pandas column names to list

Tags: python, pandas

According to this thread:
[SO: Column names to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482970/python-get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column-headers)

It should be straightforward to do convert the column names to a list. But if i do:

```
df.columns.tolist()
```

I do get:

```
[u'q_igg', u'q_hcp', u'c_igg', u'c_hcp']
```

I know, i could get rid of the u and the ' . But i would like to just get the clean names as list without any hack around. Is that possible ?

Comment: This is correct, it just indicates that the strings are Unicode strings.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Or, you could try:

```
df2 = df.columns.get_values()
```

which will give you:

```
array(['q_igg', 'q_hcp', 'c_igg', 'c_hcp'], dtype=object)
```

then:

```
df2.columns.tolist()
```

which gives you:

```
['q_igg', 'q_hcp', 'c_igg']
```

Comment: pretty verbose ..  but maybe that's the only way ..?

Comment: Slightly less verbose: `df.columns.values.tolist()`

Comment: The `get_values()` method is depreciated: "FutureWarning: The 'get_values' method is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use '.to_numpy()' or '.array' instead."

Comment: Please update your answer, since it is still the accepted answer.

Comment: try this : `list(df2)`

Answer (score 4):

Simple and easy way:
df-dataframe variable name

> `df.columns.to_list()`
>
> this will give the list of the all columns name.

Answer (score 3):

The list `[u'q_igg', u'q_hcp', u'c_igg', u'c_hcp']` contains Unicode strings: the `u` indicates that they're Unicode strings and the `'` are enclosed around each string. You can now use these names in any way you'd like in your code. See [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) for more details on Unicode strings in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just interested in printing the name without an quotes or unicode indicators, you could do something like this:

```
In [19]: print "[" + ", ".join(df) + "]"
[q_igg, q_hcp, c_igg, c_hcp]
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned the u means that its unicode converted. Anyway, the cleanest way would be to convert the colnames to ascii or something like that.

```
In [4]: cols
Out[4]: [u'q_igg', u'q_hcp', u'c_igg', u'c_hcp']

In [5]: [i.encode('ascii', 'ignore') for i in cols]
Out[5]: ['q_igg', 'q_hcp', 'c_igg', 'c_hcp'
```

The problem here is that you would lose special characters that are not encode in ascii.

A much more dirty solution would be to fetch the string representation of the list object and just replace the u. I would not use that but it might befit your needs in this special case ;-)

```
In [7]: repr(cols)
Out[7]: "[u'q_igg', u'q_hcp', u'c_igg', u'c_hcp']"
In [11]: x.replace("u", "")
Out[11]: "['q_igg', 'q_hcp', 'c_igg', 'c_hcp']"
```

see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/repr.html

Comment: Commenting on behalf of @AsheKetchum who doesn't have enough rep: The downside of `.replace` is that it might replace '**u**' if your original variables have u in their names. e.g. `"u'q_ugg'"` would become `"'q_gg'"`

Answer (score 0):

this will do the job

```
list(df2)
```