# How to select all columns that start with "durations" or "shape"?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to select all columns that have header names starting with "durations" or "shape"? (instead of defining a long list of column names). I need to select these columns and substitute blank fields by 0.

```
column_names = ['durations.blockMinutes_x',
                'durations.scheduledBlockMinutes_y']
data[column_names] = data[column_names].fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `str` methods of dataframe `startwith`:

```
df = data[data.columns[data.columns.str.startwith('durations') | data.columns.str.startwith('so')]]
df.fillna(0)
```

Or you could use `contains` method:

```
df = data.iloc[:, data.columns.str.contains('durations.*'|'shape.*') ]
df.fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `my_dataframe.columns.values.tolist()` to get the column names (based on [Get list from pandas DataFrame column headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482970/python-get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column-headers)):

```
column_names = [x for x in data.columns.values.tolist() if x.startswith("durations") or x.startswith("shape")]
```

Comment: The compiler says 'else expected'.

Comment: It must be: column_names = [x for x in data.columns.values.tolist() if x.startswith("durations") or x.startswith("shape")]

Comment: Good catch. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `select` method:

`df.select(lambda c: c.startwith('durations') or c.startswith('shape'), axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

A simple and easy way

`data[data.filter(regex='durations|shape').columns].fillna(0)`

**Sample Screenshot**

[image]