# how to select all columns that starts with a common label

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in Spark 1.6 and want to select just some columns out of it. The column names are like:

```
colA, colB, colC, colD, colE, colF-0, colF-1, colF-2
```

I know I can do like this to select specific columns:

```
df.select("colA", "colB", "colE")
```

but how to select, say "colA", "colB" and all the colF-* columns at once? Is there a way like in [Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096481/how-to-select-all-columns-that-start-with-durations-or-shape)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The process canbe broken down into following steps:

1. First grab the column names with `df.columns`,
2. then filter down to just the column names you want `.filter(_.startsWith("colF"))`. This gives you an array of Strings.
3. But the select takes `select(String, String*)`. Luckily select for columns is `select(Column*)`, so finally convert the Strings into Columns with `.map(df(_))`,
4. and finally turn the Array of Columns into a var arg with `: _*`.

`df.select(df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("colF")).map(df(_)) : _*).show`

This filter could be made more complex (same as Pandas). It is however a rather ugly solution (IMO):

```
df.select(df.columns.filter(x => (x.equals("colA") || x.startsWith("colF"))).map(df(_)) : _*).show
```

If the list of other columns is fixed you could also merge a fixed array of columns names with filtered array.

```
df.select((Array("colA", "colB") ++ df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("colF"))).map(df(_)) : _*).show
```

Comment: thanks but how to select also other columns, like stated in the question?

Comment: the exact solution to my problem comes out of a mixture of your second and third solution... thanks so much, you totally master the topic

Comment: any ready-to-use solution in pyspark (python not scala) ?

Comment: Could you explain what this underscore does?

Comment: Also I get the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'`

Answer (score 13):

Python (tested in Azure Databricks)

```
selected_columns = [column for column in df.columns if column.startswith("colF")]
df2 = df.select(selected_columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

In PySpark, use: **colRegex** to select columns starting with **colF**
Whit the sample:

```
colA, colB, colC, colD, colE, colF-0, colF-1, colF-2
```

Apply:

```
df.select(col("colA"), col("colB"), df.colRegex("`(colF)+?.+`")).show()
```

The result is:

```
colA, colB, colF-0, colF-1, colF-2
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a function that does that. Read the comments to see how it works.

```scala
  /**
    * Given a sequence of prefixes, select suitable columns from [[DataFrame]]
    * @param columnPrefixes Sequence of prefixes
    * @param dF Incoming [[DataFrame]]
    * @return [[DataFrame]] with prefixed columns selected
    */
  def selectPrefixedColumns(columnPrefixes: Seq[String], dF: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    // Find out if given column name matches any of the provided prefixes
    def colNameStartsWith: String => Boolean = (colName: String) =>
        columnsPrefix.map(prefix => colName.startsWith(prefix)).reduce(_ || _)
    // Filter columns list by checking against given prefixes sequence
    val columns = dF.columns.filter(colNameStartsWith)
    // Select filtered columns list
    dF.select(columns.head, columns.tail:_*)
  }
```