# Creating new dataframe columns from existing dataframe column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe (stockData) which has stock data for three different types of data (indexed by date) these are LAST,VOLUME,MKTCAP.

here is the head of the dataframe(stockData)

```
                           BBG.XLON.BTA.S_LAST  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_VOLUME  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_MKTCAP  \
date                                                                            
2001-01-02                  572               26605510               37494.60   
2001-01-03                  560               24715470               36708.00   
2001-01-04                  613               52781855               40182.15   
2001-01-05                  630               56600152               41296.50   
2001-01-08                  633               41014402               41493.15   

            BBG.XLON.VOD.S_LAST  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_VOLUME  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_MKTCAP  
date                                                                           
2001-01-02                  NaN                    NaN                    NaN  
2001-01-03               225.00              444328736            145216.0020  
2001-01-04               239.00              488568000            154251.6643  
2001-01-05               242.25              237936704            156349.2288  
2001-01-08               227.75              658059776            146990.8642
```

Is there a way to take one of these fields for all of the stocks create a new set of columns from this data with a new post fix (_HOLIDAY) so I end up with:

```
              BBG.XLON.BTA.S_LAST  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_VOLUME  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_MKTCAP  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_HOLIDAY  \
date                                                                            
2001-01-02                  572               26605510               37494.60                   NaN  
2001-01-03                  560               24715470               36708.00                   NaN  
2001-01-04                  613               52781855               40182.15                   NaN  
2001-01-05                  630               56600152               41296.50                   NaN  
2001-01-08                  633               41014402               41493.15                   NaN  

            BBG.XLON.VOD.S_LAST  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_VOLUME  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_MKTCAP  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_HOLIDAY  
date                                                                           
2001-01-02                  NaN                    NaN                    NaN                   NaN  
2001-01-03               225.00              444328736            145216.0020                   NaN  
2001-01-04               239.00              488568000            154251.6643                   NaN  
2001-01-05               242.25              237936704            156349.2288                   NaN  
2001-01-08               227.75              658059776            146990.8642                   NaN
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is that what you want?

```
In [56]: newcols = df.columns.str.replace(r'\.S_.*','.S_HOLIDAY').unique().tolist()

In [57]: newcols
Out[57]: ['BBG.XLON.BTA.S_HOLIDAY', 'BBG.XLON.VOD.S_HOLIDAY']
```

then you can easily add new columns:

```
In [65]: for col in newcols:
   ....:         df[col] = np.nan
   ....:

In [66]: df
Out[66]:
            BBG.XLON.BTA.S_LAST  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_VOLUME  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_MKTCAP  \
2001-01-02                  572               26605510               37494.60
2001-01-03                  560               24715470               36708.00
2001-01-04                  613               52781855               40182.15
2001-01-05                  630               56600152               41296.50
2001-01-08                  633               41014402               41493.15

            BBG.XLON.VOD.S_LAST  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_VOLUME  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_MKTCAP  \
2001-01-02                  NaN                    NaN                    NaN
2001-01-03               225.00            444328736.0            145216.0020
2001-01-04               239.00            488568000.0            154251.6643
2001-01-05               242.25            237936704.0            156349.2288
2001-01-08               227.75            658059776.0            146990.8642

            BBG.XLON.BTA.S_HOLIDAY  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_HOLIDAY
2001-01-02                     NaN                     NaN
2001-01-03                     NaN                     NaN
2001-01-04                     NaN                     NaN
2001-01-05                     NaN                     NaN
2001-01-08                     NaN                     NaN
```

If the order of columns is important for you you can reorder it like this:

```
df = df[ordered_column_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DataFrame.columns.values`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482970/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column-headers) to get the column names and then strip the substring after and including the last dot (.):

```
names=[s[:s.rfind('.')] for s in df.columns.values]
```

Here I assume that your dataframe is called `df`. 
This will result in duplicate names (for `.S_LAST`, `.S_VOLUME` and `.S_MKTCAP`). Now you can use [`numpy.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to remove duplicates:

```
import numpy as np
uNames=np.unique(names)
```

And now you can add your new column `<name>.S_HOLIDAY` assigning a NaN value:

```
for n in uNames:
   df[n+'.S_HOLIDAY']=np.NaN
```