# exporting feature importance to csv from random forest

Tags: python, csv, pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest

Hi I would like to create a .csv with 2 columns: the feature importance of a random forest model and the name of that feature. And to be sure that the match between numeric value and variable name is correct

Here it's an example but I cannot export to .csv correclty

```
test_features = test[["area","product", etc.]].values

# Create the target 
target = test["churn"].values

pred_forest = my_forest.predict(test_features)

# Print the score of the fitted random forest
print(my_forest.score(test_features, target))


importance = my_forest.feature_importances_


pd.DataFrame({"IMP": importance, "features":test_features }).to_csv('forest_0407.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: How does this fail? this looks a bit fishy to me as you're trying to match the feature importance against the features df itself which is incorrect as the feature importance is the columns

Comment: I'm confused because is I print "importance" I can see only an array, but I'm not sure to which feature is matches, for that I would like to check both names and values. the message error is this:  
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional

Comment: try this this for features `test.columns.tolist()`.

Comment: @shivsn the lazy typists version is [`list(df)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482970/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column-headers) to get the columns as a list

Comment: @EdChum nice I didn't know that thank you.

Comment: @EdChum  list(df) or test.columns.tolist() give me only a list of variables, I would like to see in one column the name and in another column the value of importance

Comment: I think what you want is something like `feat_imp = pd.Series(importance, index=df.columns)`

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
x = list(zip(my_forest.feature_importances_,list of features you are using))
x = pandas.DataFrame(x,columns=["Importance","Feature_Name"])
```