# How do you suppress a warning/error in Python and or Cloud9 IDE?

Tags: python, cloud9-ide, cloud9

I am using the Cloud9 IDE and have created a Python project.

However, I keep getting the error in my editor on one line, which is not an error when i run it, which says:

```
Instance of 'dict' has no 'columns' member
```

How can I suppress this error, either using Python syntax or Cloud9 syntax?

NOTE: when I run the code, it does not result in an error. My IDE editor simply thinks its an error and warns me.

```
    xl      = pd.ExcelFile(dataFileUrl)
    sheets  = xl.sheet_names
    data    = xl.parse(sheets[0])


    # the ERROR warning is on the line for data.columns
    for ecol in expectedCols:
        if (ecol in data.columns) == False:
            return {
                'fail':   True,
                'code':   402,
                'msg':    "Incomplete data. Missing: " + ecol
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comment by @LucG, I tried to get the list of column headers in a different way.

Hence following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482970/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column-headers), I used

```
list(df)
```

instead of

```
df.columns
```

This suppressed the warning.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known limitation of PyLint as mentioned in their [documentation](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:e1101)..

> #### E1101
>
> ```
> %s %r has no %r member
>
> Function %r has no %r member
> Variable %r has no %r member
> . . .
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> Used when an object (variable, function, …) is accessed for a non-existent member.
>
> False positives: This message may report object members that are created dynamically, but exist at the time they are accessed.

Try adding the comment `# pylint: disable=no-member` at the top of your page (I've never played around with modifying PyLint before, so I'm note entirely sure how this system of configuring via comments works...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try` (equivalent to try/catch or rescue/ensure in other languages)

```
try:
   ecol in data.columns:
except:
    #Handle differently if there is a problem or pass
    return {
            'fail':   True,
            'code':   402,
            'msg':    "Incomplete data. Missing: " + ecol
        }
```

Comment: not working, I am still getting the error message in my IDE. So the issue is not that I get the error when i execute it, I just get a warning sign in my IDE editor.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the IDE. `except` without a specific Exception should execute the code. Can you post the relevant code? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730764/try-except-in-python-how-do-you-properly-ignore-exceptions

Comment: added it more text text

Comment: Can you try what I added?

Comment: Yes tried it. Does not work.. still the error. So maybe its the IDE formatter.

Comment: I changed it one more time. I think this is probably what you are after. You can use `ecol` regularly after the except. If this does not work, then it is almost certainly the IDE

Comment: This is an anti-pattern and should not be done: https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/no_exception_type_specified.html#anti-pattern 

You should better try to understand why your IDE says that... It is probably because something is wrong somewhere if the bug is not documented/reported in the Internet.

Comment: @LucG looking for the bug for a while now. Cant find anything on it.