# Get column names from pandas DataFrame in format dtype:object

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a similar doubt to the one in the mentioned link. Instead of returning column names in a list, I want column names in the format dtype:object. 
For example,

```
A
B
C
D
Name:x,dtype:object
```

I am using Excel file in xlsx format.

Link: [Get list from pandas DataFrame column headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482970/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column-headers)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) first for `df` and then `Series` constructor or [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) for `Series` from column names:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  1  4  7  1
1  2  5  8  3
2  3  6  9  5

s = pd.Series(df.columns.values, name='x')
print (s)
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
Name: x, dtype: object

s1 = df.columns.to_series().rename('x')
print (s1)
A    A
B    B
C    C
D    D
Name: x, dtype: object
```