# Is pandas.DataFrame.columns.values.tolist() the same as pandas.DataFrame.columns.tolist()

Tags: python, pandas

We have both code popping up in our codebase

```
pandas.DataFrame.columns.values.tolist()
pandas.DataFrame.columns.tolist()
```

Are these always identical? I'm not sure why the `values` variant pops up in the places it does, seems like the direct `columns.tolist()` is all that's needed to get the column names. I'm looking to clean up the code a bit if this is the case.

Introspecting a bit seems to suggest values is just some implementation detail being a numpy.ndarray

```
>>> import pandas
>>> d = pandas.DataFrame( { 'a' : [1,2,3], 'b' : [0,1,3]} )
>>> d
   a  b
0  1  0
1  2  1
2  3  3
>>> type(d.columns)
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>
>>> type(d.columns.values)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(d.columns.tolist())
<class 'list'>
>>> type(d.columns.values.tolist())
<class 'list'>
>>> d.columns.values
array(['a', 'b'], dtype=object)
>>> d.columns.values.tolist()
['a', 'b']
>>> d.columns
Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')
>>> d.columns.tolist()
['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Output is same, but if really big `df` timings are different:

```
np.random.seed(23)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size=(5,10000)))
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
print (df)

In [90]: %timeit df.columns.values.tolist()
10000 loops, best of 3: 79.5 µs per loop

In [91]: %timeit df.columns.tolist()
10000 loops, best of 3: 173 µs per loop
```

Also uses different functions:

[`Index.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.values.html) with [numpy.ndarray.tolist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html)

[`Index.tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.tolist.html)

Thanks [`Mitch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45152534/is-pandas-dataframe-columns-values-tolist-the-same-as-pandas-dataframe-columns/45152599#comment77274342_45152599) for another solution:

```
In [93]: %timeit list(df.columns.values)
1000 loops, best of 3: 169 µs per loop
```

Comment: Very good, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29494537/1330381) to a question about how to get the column headers as a list and it looks like there was an API simplification at some point.

Comment: `tolist` for an Index object just calls `list(self.values)` from what I can see, so the performance difference seen here is just `df.columns.values.tolist()` vs `list(df.columns.values)`.

Comment: And I'm not advocating for that solution necessarily, I just wanted to point out that `list(df.columns.values)` is wholly equivalent to `df.columns.tolist()`. So the performance difference here is the `list` built-in function versus the NumPy array `.tolist()`, the latter of which seems faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = pandas.DataFrame( { 'a' : [1,2,3], 'b' : [0,1,3]} )
```

or you can simply do

```
list(d)# it is same with d.columns.tolist()
Out[327]: ['a', 'b']

#  Time 
% timeit list(df) # after run the time , this is the slowest on my side . 
10000 loops, best of 3: 135 µs per loop
```