# Convert multiple columns to string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with different data types. I want to convert more than one column in the data frame to string type. I have individually done for each column but want to know if there is an efficient way?

So at present I am doing something like this:

```
repair['SCENARIO']=repair['SCENARIO'].astype(str)

repair['SERVICE_TYPE']= repair['SERVICE_TYPE'].astype(str)
```

I want a function that would help me pass multiple columns and convert them to strings.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

To convert [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15891038/6060083) columns to string, include a *list* of columns to your above-mentioned command:

```
df[['one', 'two', 'three']] = df[['one', 'two', 'three']].astype(str)
# add as many column names as you like.
```

That means that *one* way to convert [all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19482970/6060083) columns is to construct the list of columns like this:

```
all_columns = list(df) # Creates list of all column headers
df[all_columns] = df[all_columns].astype(str)
```

Note that the latter can also be done directly (see comments).

Comment: For all columns, how about `df = df.astype(str)` ?

Comment: Yes, also works, absolutely - I just posted this solution to stick with the concept of lists

Comment: Thanks sudonym... I was actually looking for something like a function that would take columns in a data frame and convert them to string. I should be able to change the column names as required though the first solution works perfectly and I did implement it.

Comment: Is there any performance difference between the two? I tried `df = df.astype(str)` shape (50000, 23000) and it crashed (in interactive mode). Thank you

Comment: Wondering why this doesn't works if the list of columns has a single element...

Comment: This method worked for me. However, I previously tried `df.iloc[:,9:].astype(str)` to select a slice range but `df.info()` said they were still int64. In addition, if I assigned that call to my original df e.g. df=`df.iloc[:,9:].astype(str)`, the new df would only have those 9 columns. Not sure why only this answer worked for me.

Answer (score 22):

I know this is an old question, but I was looking for a way to turn all columns with an object dtype to strings as a workaround for a bug I discovered in rpy2.  I'm working with large dataframes, so didn't want to list each column explicitly.  This seemed to work well for me so I thought I'd share in case it helps someone else.

```
stringcols = df.select_dtypes(include='object').columns
df[stringcols] = df[stringcols].fillna('').astype(str)
```

The "fillna('')" prevents NaN entries from getting converted to the string 'nan' by replacing with an empty string instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use list comprehension:

```
df = [df[col_name].astype(str) for col_name in df.columns]
```

You can also insert a condition to test if the columns should be converted - for example:

```
df = [df[col_name].astype(str) for col_name in df.columns if 'to_str' in col_name]
```

Comment: These solutions overwrite your pandas dataframe with a list