# Dynamically rename column name in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataframe which will automatically generate multiple columns like result1, result2, result3, result4 etc. I want to rename the last result i.e result4 in this case. The number of columns will be new everytime so I can't use command like

```
df.rename(columns={'result4': 'Final_result'}, inplace=True)
```

How can I do it? what command will be good to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is how to get a list of the columns so you can do `[-1]` to it.

Perhaps [Get list from pandas DataFrame column headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482970/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column-headers) which leads to:

```
df.rename(columns={ df.columns.tolist()[-1]: 'Final_result'}, inplace=True)
```

Untested.

Comment: Thank you for replying. But I nhave multiple columns with similar name like cash1 cash2 cash3, interest1, interest2, interest3, result1, result2, result3. How can I do it then?