# Column names not printing python SQL results

Tags: python, sql, csv

I am trying to get the column names to print for my code below, it only prints the results of the queries, the results being underneath each other.

Is there a way to append the column names above each query result? Or is there a way to append custom column names about each result?

```
cur = db.cursor()
cur = db2.cursor()
cur = db3.cursor()

#SQL Queries

dbQuery="SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Name) FROM blah;"

dbQuery2="SELECT COUNT(Pause) FROM blah WHERE Pause = 1;"

dbQuery3="SELECT COUNT(Pause) FROM blah WHERE Pause = 0;"

result = []

cur.execute(dbQuery)

result.extend(cur.fetchall())

cur.execute(dbQuery2)

result.extend(cur.fetchall())

cur.execute(dbQuery3)

result.extend(cur.fetchall())

column_names = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
fp = open('Result_Set.csv', 'w')
myFile = csv.writer(fp)
myFile.writerow(column_names) 
myFile.writerows(result)
fp.close()
```

I feel as though I am missing something simple.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482970/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column-headers

Comment: You don't have any column names in your sql.   select  count(distinct names) as mynames from mytable.