# Pandas Column names to list - correct method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I cannot find any resources about wether one of the following three methods for getting a list of column names is preferred over the others.
The first and simplest, seems to work with my current example. Is there any reason I should not use it ?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,3))
>>> df.columns
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)



>>> list(df.columns)
[0, 1, 2]
>>> df.columns.get_values().tolist()
[0, 1, 2]
>>> list(df.columns.get_values())
[0, 1, 2]
```

**Update**

Performance - related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27236748/605328

Comment: pick the one that has your preferred balance of readability and performance.

Comment: I feel like there's no difference among the three. For me, the easier and simpler the better, so I chooose #1.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482970/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column-headers you can do `list(df)` if you hate typing `my_dataframe.columns.values.tolist()` if you want speed

Comment: @coldspeed my question is wether all these methods are equal, or if there is a difference. I don't think its duplicate.

Comment: @Giannis the differences and benefits are discussed at length in the other question.

Comment: Fair enough, should have scrolled past the first few answers.

Comment: `[*df]` if you really hate typing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also use:

```
df.columns.tolist()
```

Comment: I guess, my question is if one of them is more "correct", i.e there is some edge case that the others will fail.

Comment: None of them will fail. I just gave you the one which is quite fast.