# How to create dictionary from column names as values and variables as keys x1, x2, ... , xn?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, dictionary, variables

I have a dataframe with 162 columns, and I want to rename the columns to variables x1, x2, ... , x(n), but keep the current column names in a dictionary for reference.  I've tried a few loop methods but am not having much luck - I want to avoid doing this manually considering the number of columns. Any input is much appreciated~! Thank you.

Ex: from column names "red", "green", "blue", ... (162 total colors = column names),
create dictionary {'x1':'red', 'x2':'blue,...,'xn':'lastcolor'}

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as

```
columns = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
d = {f'x{i}': c for i, c in enumerate(columns, 1)}
```

Comment: this is a manual method, which is exatly what is **not** asked

Answer (score 0):

To automate this, you need to get the column names from the dataframe itself. But the `DataFrame` behaves like a dictionary, so iterating over it gives you back its keys (related SO question with more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482970/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column-headers)). Building on Eugene's answer, you should be able to do

```
new_to_old = {f'x{i}': old_name for i, old_name in enumerate(columns, df)}
```

where `df` is your dataframe.
If you want to be more explicit, you could do

```
new_to_old = {f'x{i}': old_name for i, old_name in enumerate(columns, df.keys())}
```

or

```
new_to_old = {f'x{i}': old_name for i, old_name in enumerate(columns, df.columns.values)}
```

Which you choose is mostly personal preference, unless you care about performance, in which case you should use `df.columns.values`.

To rename the columns themselves, you could use `DataFrame.rename` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)) with the inverse of `new_to_old`:

```py
old_to_new = {old: new for new, old in in new_to_old.items()}

df.rename(columns = old_to_new)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This worked just as I wanted it to!