# Pandas Dataframe keys to array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want an array of values from dataframe.keys() method. But it returns an Index object, that have the header values array as a member. But I want only that array, no other details.

```
header_values=features_dataframe.keys()
print(header_values)
```

**Output**

> Index(['header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4',
> 'header5','Target'],
> dtype='object')

But I want

> ['header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4',
> 'header5','Target']

Comment: I'm Sorry, but I'm not looking for Index, instead looking for headers!

Comment: Hi, please take a deep breath. I've re-assessed this and changed the duplicate to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482970/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column-headers). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55491499/4909087) I personally endorse.

Comment: Okay :) but you can mark as duplicate without negative voting :p

Comment: Voting is anonymous here, please don't assume that someone downvoted you as you could always be assuming incorrectly. In this case I did not touch the downvote button on your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it:

```
header_values = list(features_dataframe.keys())
print(header_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
list(features_dataframe.index)
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect, it returns the index instead of the columns.