# Trying to use df.columns to get list of headers in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I made a pandas dataframe, but when I call df.columns I get RangeIndex(start=0, stop=17, step=1). What is happening? I just want to get a list of my headers

Comment: It's very difficult for someone to help you with what you have given here.  You should post a [reproduce-able example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others might be able to help you out more

Comment: How did you make the dataframe? If you didn't specify headers (or use something like read_csv) then the columns will just be 0, 1, 2, 3 ... but that is implemented via the `RangeIndex`. `df[0]` should get you the first column.

Answer (score 0):

This post covers your question in detail:
[Get list from pandas DataFrame column headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482970/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column-headers)

Briefly, you can use: `df.columns.tolist()` or `df.columns.values.tolist()`