# displaying columns names of dataFrame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an xlsx file having about 100 columns. When I use `df.columns` function then it display some of the first and some last columns but not all of them. I want to display(print) all of the column name (headings) though for loop. How can I do it?

Comment: Try `print(df.columns.tolist())` to get all the items. It will print out all the cols

Comment: [python3.5 version: `[*df]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55491499/4909087)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for col in df.columns:
    print(col)
```