# Why does `list(<pd.DataFrame>)` return a list of column names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say `df` is a typical `pandas.DataFrame` instance, I am trying to understand how come `list(df)` would return a list of column names.

The goal here is for me to track it down in the source code to understand how `list(<pd.DataFrame>)` returns a list of column names.

#### So far, the best resources I've found are the following:

- [Get a list from Pandas DataFrame column headers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19482970/13697827)

  - Summary: There are multiple ways of getting a list of DataFrame column names, and each varies either in performance or idiomatic convention.
- [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21315199/13697827)

  - Summary: DataFrame follows a dict-like convention, thus coercing with `list()` would return a list of the keys of this dict-like structure.
- [`pandas.DataFrame` source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/frame.py#L462-L11066):

  - I can't find within the source code that point to how `list()` would create a list of column head names.

Comment: I don't know anything about pandas, but I would look for an `__iter__()` method on the DataFrame class.

Comment: Thanks, seems like `pd.DataFrame` class inherited the `__iter__()` method from its parent, `NDFrame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, as you have correctly stated in your question. One can think of a pandas dataframe as a list of lists (or more correctly a dict like object).

Take a look at this code which takes a `dict` and parses it into a `df`.

```
import pandas as pd

# create a dataframe
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)

x = list(df)
print(x)

x = list(d)
print(x)
```

The result in both cases (for the dataframe `df` and the dict `d`) is this:

```
['col1', 'col2']
['col1', 'col2']
```

This result confirms your thinking that a "*DataFrame follows a dict-like convention*" .

Answer (score 2):

DataFrames are iterable. That's why you can pass them to the `list` constructor.

`list(df)` is equivalent to `[c for c in df]`. In both cases, `DataFrame.__iter__` is called.

When you iterate over a DataFrame, you get the column names.

Why? Because the developers probably thought this is a nice thing to have.

Looking at the source, [`__iter__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.4.1/pandas/core/generic.py#L1953-L1962) returns an iterator over the attribute `_info_axis`, which seems to be the [internal name](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.4.1/pandas/core/frame.py#L10755) of the columns.