# How to put the value of dataframe in array form?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:
[image]

I wish to have extract all the data for value column in form of array, which the output should be:
**[nan, 47, 47.9, 48.6]**

Anyone can share me the ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get list from pandas dataframe column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341271/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) for `numpy array` + [`numpy.ndarray.tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) for `list`:

```
L = df['value'].values.tolist()
#alternative
#L = df['value'].tolist()
```

Or convert to `list`:

```
L = list(df['value'])
```

EDIT:

It seems you need convert to `float` first by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':['nan','47','47.9','48.6']})
print (df)
  value
0   nan
1    47
2  47.9
3  48.6

L1 = df['value'].values.tolist()
print (L1)
['nan', '47', '47.9', '48.6']

L2 = df['value'].astype(float).values.tolist()
print (L2)
[nan, 47.0, 47.9, 48.6]
```

because if `float` all values get different output - `47.0` not `47`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[np.nan,47,47.9,48.6]})
   value
0    NaN
1   47.0
2   47.9
3   48.6

L = df['value'].values.tolist()
print (L)
[nan, 47.0, 47.9, 48.6]
```

EDIT1:

If `astype` return error e.g:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'

then need [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert non numeric to `NaN`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[np.nan,47,47.9,48.6, 'a']})
print (df)
  value
0   NaN
1    47
2  47.9
3  48.6
4     a

print (pd.to_numeric(df['value'], errors='coerce'))
0     NaN
1    47.0
2    47.9
3    48.6
4     NaN
Name: value, dtype: float64

L = pd.to_numeric(df['value'], errors='coerce').values.tolist()
print (L)
[nan, 47.0, 47.9, 48.6, nan]
```