# Pandas help: convert column from delimted string to column array

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv loaded into a panda dataframe. One of the columns contains semi colon delimited list of words like

Beach holiday;Plenty of space;Pool

and I would like to turn this into an array or collection like
["Beach holiday","Plenty of space","Pool"]

Alternatively could create a new column derived from the orginal.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide example dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended solution, especially if you have the same number of `;` separators in each string, is to create a dataframe of `object` dtype series, with each element a single string:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Beach holiday;Plenty of space;Pool',
                         'Mountain holiday;Plenty of grey;Ice']})

df = df['A'].str.split(';', expand=True)

print(df)

                  0                1     2
0     Beach holiday  Plenty of space  Pool
1  Mountain holiday   Plenty of grey   Ice
```

Creating a series of lists, the alternative, is **not** recommended; it involves a *nested* layer of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you want the headers to be in a list

```
list(df.columns.values)
```

or

```
df[col_name].tolist()
```

also, check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341271/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 0):

You may check `converters`

```
TESTDATA = StringIO("""
 A,B
1,Beach holiday;Plenty of space;Pool
1,Beach holiday;Plenty of space;Pool
    """)
df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA ,converters={'B':lambda x : x.split(';')})
df
Out[147]: 
    A                                       B
0   1  [Beach holiday, Plenty of space, Pool]
1   1  [Beach holiday, Plenty of space, Pool]
```