# Convert a dataframe column into a list of object

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to read a CSV which contains a `phone_number` field (string), however, I need to convert this field into the below JSON format
`[{'phone_number':'+01 373643222'}]` and put it under a new column name called `phone_numbers`, how can I do that?

Searched online but the examples I found are converting the all the columns into JSON by using `to_json()` which is apparently cannot solve my case.

Below is an example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
                   'phone_number': ['+1 569-483-2388', '+1 555-555-1212', '+1 432-867-5309']})
```

Comment: please create an example for your question, check [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: tolist() should do the job. Check answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341271/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column

Comment: `[df["phone_number"].to_json()]` will convert the Series to json in a list

Comment: it is not working by doing `df['phone_numbers'] = [df["phone_number"].to_json()]`

Comment: do you need: `df['phone_numbers']=[f'phone_number:{i}' for i in df['phone_number']]` or `df['phone_numbers']=[f'[phone_number:{i}]' for i in df['phone_number']]`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use map function like this

```py
df["phone_numbers"] = df["phone_number"].map(lambda x: [{"phone_number": x}] )

display(df)
```