# Define a column from a csv as "Y"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to define a column from a csv file as a Letter. For example, I want to name the second and the third column, respectively, as X and Y.

I have an CSV file where the values are separated by ";". The columns have 68 rows and the first row/header is the name of the column. I would like to name the second and the third column, respectively, as X and Y.
Using pandas i've tried

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\t1079577\Desktop\DATABASE.csv', sep=";")
x='com_proc'
y='result_op'
```

It doesent read the entire column.

Comment: I didn't express myself well enough. I would like to call the entire column (values included) to use them, as if it was a vector with 68 coordinates

Comment: `x = df['column_name'].values.tolist()` will do what you want.  However, this is a poor way to use a dataframe.

Comment: It worked! Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get list from pandas dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341271/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column)