# List holding unnecessary information including data type

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, series

I am writing a code in which I have to convert columns from a data frame into lists. One particular list is picking up not just information from the column but also the name of the column and data type in each row. What is driving me crazy is that I am using the exact same line of code for other columns and it is working perfectly fine. Only this particular list is working this way. I am including the code below maintaining integrity without losing confidentiality to the best of my ability

```
averagecrimerating=[]
lawandorderrating=[]
for i in range (0,len(uniqueyears)):
  averagecrimerating.append(tv[(tv['date']==uniqueyears[i])].av_rating)
  lawandorderrating.append(lawandorder[(lawandorder['date']==uniqueyears[i])].av_rating)
```

What I expect the lawandorderrating list to look like when I print it is

```
[8.6219
 8.7060
 8.001
 8.6406
 6.5898
 8.4387
 8.8197
 8.7952
 8.9302
 8.886
 8.9351]
```

but what it looks like is

```
[0    8.6219
 1    8.7060
 Name: Average_rating, dtype: float64, 2    8.001
 Name: Average_rating, dtype: float64, 3    8.6406
 Name: Average_rating, dtype: float64, 4    6.5898
 Name: Average_rating, dtype: float64, 5    8.4387
 Name: Average_rating, dtype: float64, 6    8.8197
 Name: Average_rating, dtype: float64, 7    8.7952
 Name: Average_rating, dtype: float64, 8    8.9302
 Name: Average_rating, dtype: float64, 9    8.886
 Name: Average_rating, dtype: float64, 10    8.9351
 Name: Average_rating, dtype: float64]
```

Another list averagecrimerating created just before this using the exact same code is working perfectly fine. What am I missing?

Edit: adding sample data source
titleId seasonNumber    title   date    av_rating   share   genres 
tt0806901   44  Polizeiruf 110  2015    7   0   Crime,Drama 
tt0203259   20  Law & Order: Special Victims Unit   2018    8.6219  0.07    Crime,Drama,Mystery 
tt0118401   19  Midsomer Murders    2017    7.3916  0.05    Crime,Drama,Mystery 
tt0098844   18  Law & Order 2008    7.847   0.31    Crime,Drama,Mystery

[A snip of the actual data looks as given in pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmTPS.png)

Comment: what does the source data look like?

Comment: The source data are csv files with the following keys 'titleID','seasonNumber','title','Year','Av_rating','share' and 'genres'. The data frame tv was was obtained from the master file. The data frame lawandorder was created by pulling out data from the data frame tv which had 'title' = "Law & Order: Special Victims Unity". Please see code used below
   lawandorder = tv[tv.title=="Law & Order: Special Victims Unit"].copy()

Comment: Can you post a small sample of it in your question so we can test your code and see what it’s doing!

Comment: Just added sample data. Not sure how to format it so that it looks right. Hope what I added helps.

Comment: Is there a reason the recommended method [tolist()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341271/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column) of converting a dataframe column to list is not used?  [More](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-tolist/)

Comment: No reason other than the fact that I am a newbie coder. So I didn't know that it was the recommended approach and I didn't know you could use conditional expressions in tolist(). Will check it out and update on the output.