# Python spaCy - Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got DataFrame)

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am trying to use spaCy and I am having trouble with this error that I am receiving.

## Set up spaCy

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
parser = English()

import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

comment = data['comment']
```

This is the line of code causing the error:

```
comment = nlp(comment)
```

Comment: What does `data` look like?

Comment: Data has a several columns, scores and one of the columns I am doing the nlp on is comments.

Comment: @AmandaMorrow Did you ever find a solution? I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

```
data['comment']
```

returns a pandas series. Spacy is expecting a list. You should convert the pandas series to list using tolist() command and then pass to Spacy - refer to [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341271/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column)

```
comment = data['comment'].tolist()
```