# Scraping free proxy list with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

So I'm using pandas and requests to scrape IP's from https://free-proxy-list.net/ but how do I cover this code

```
import pandas as pd

resp = requests.get('https://free-proxy-list.net/')
df = pd.read_html(resp.text)[0]

df = (df[(df['Anonymity'] == 'elite proxy')])

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

so that the output is list of IP's without anything else. I managed to remove index and only added elite proxy but I can't make a variable that is a list with only IP's and without index.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get list from pandas dataframe column or row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341271/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column-or-row)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `loc` to slice directly the column for the matching rows, and `to_list` to convert to list:

```
df.loc[df['Anonymity'].eq('elite proxy'), 'IP Address'].to_list()
```

output: `['134.119.xxx.xxx', '173.249.xxx.xxx'...]`

Answer (score 0):

To get the contents of the 'IP Address' column, subset to the 'IP address' column and use `.to_list()`.

Here's how:

```py
print(df['IP Address'].to_list())
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to accomplish something like below:

```
print(df['IP Address'].to_string(index=False))
```

Also It would be a good idea, after filtering your dataframe to reset its index like below:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

So the code snippet would be something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

resp = requests.get('https://free-proxy-list.net/')
df = pd.read_html(resp.text)[0]

df = (df[(df['Anonymity'] == 'elite proxy')])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(df['IP Address'].to_string(index=False))
```