# for loop repeats 17 times

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, printing

I have the following code, but when I execute it, it prints the age_groups_list 17 times,

Any idea why?

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv(r"file location")
age_groups_list = []
for var in file[1:]:
    age = file.iloc[:, 10]
    age_groups_list.append(age)
print(age_groups_list)
```

the idea is that I have a csv file with 16,000 (+) rows and 20 columns, I am picking the age group from index 10, adding it to a list and then print the list, however when printing the list, it does it for 17 time, this image shows the end of the printing output.
[image]
Any idea what am I doing wrong here?
thanks

Comment: Please post a [mre].  What does `file` contain?  Examine it, then replace the `csv` read with a simple assignment of that value.  Then the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: I don't see any way this can print more than once, since the `print()` line isn't in the loop.

Comment: If you want to get a list of a dataframe column, use `.tolist()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341271/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column-or-row

Comment: You extract the same column, `age = file.iloc[:, 10]`,  **every** iteration of the for loop.

Comment: [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)

Answer (score 0):

file.iloc[:,10] already gives you all the data you need the loop is useless
what you see is actually a list of lists.
change it to this:

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv(r"file location")
age_groups_list = file.iloc[:, 10]
print(age_groups_list)
```

Comment: It works in this way, thanks, however, any idea why it is behaving like this? and also I want to have it in a list, thanks again

Comment: to have it as a list you can use
age_groups_list = file.iloc[:, 10].to_list()