# I need to random shuffle rows of two pandas DataFrames in the same random way

Tags: python, dataframe, random, shuffle

I have two dataframes, A and B , with dimension MxN which rows I want to random shuffle. A and B have the same column names and indexes. I know how to shuffle data inside each column with df.apply(np.random.shuffle) method, but it permutate differently each column. I want that if the first row of A becames the second row after shuffle, the first row of B becames the second row too, etc. How can I do what I want?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576430/shuffle-dataframe-rows#34879805

Answer (score 2):

I was blind. It is simple. If we have a list of permutations PMT. We can do this:

```
A_new = A.iloc[PMT]
B_new = B.iloc[PMT]
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use pandas but works

```
from random import shuffle
ind_list=[i for i in range(M)]
shuffle(ind_list)
A=A[ind_list,:]
B=B[ind_list,:]
```