# Shuffle rows by a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following example of dataframe.

```
    c1     c2
0   1       a
1   2       b
2   3       c
3   4       d
4   5       e
```

Given a template `c1 = [3, 2, 5, 4, 1]`, I want to change the order of the rows based on the new order of column `c1`, so it will look like:

```
    c1     c2
0    3      c
1    2      b
2    5      e
3    4      d
4    1      a
```

I found the following thread, but the shuffle is random. Cmmiw.

[Shuffle DataFrame rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576430/shuffle-dataframe-rows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If values are unique in list and also in `c1` column use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
df = df.set_index('c1').reindex(c1).reset_index()
print (df)
   c1 c2
0   3  c
1   2  b
2   5  e
3   4  d
4   1  a
```

General solution working with duplicates in list and also in column:

```
c1 = [3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3]

#create df from list 
list_df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':c1})
print (list_df)
   c1
0   3
1   2
2   5
3   4
4   1
5   3
6   2
7   3

#helper column for count duplicates values
df['g'] = df.groupby('c1').cumcount()
list_df['g'] = list_df.groupby('c1').cumcount()

#merge together, create index from column and remove g column
df = list_df.merge(df).drop('g', axis=1)
print (df)
   c1 c2
0   3  c
1   2  b
2   5  e
3   4  d
4   1  a
5   3  c
```

Comment: the list with unique value is my case. perfect solution. thanks! However I still don't understand the second case. why does the result have 5th index? @jezrael

Comment: @bakka - second solution working if there are multiple same values like `3` and `2` in list, then `reindex` raise error. So is necessary count each value by `cumcount` and then merge - first dupe of list with first dupe of column.

Answer (score 3):

#### `merge`

You can create a dataframe with the column specified in the wanted order then `merge`.
One advantage of this approach is that it gracefully handles duplicates in either `df.c1` or the list `c1`.  If duplicates not wanted then care must be taken to handle them prior to reordering.

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'c1': c1})

d1.merge(df)

   c1 c2
0   3  c
1   2  b
2   5  e
3   4  d
4   1  a
```

---

#### `searchsorted`

This is less robust but will work if `df.c1` is:

- already sorted
- one-to-one mapping

---

```
df.iloc[df.c1.searchsorted(c1)]

   c1 c2
2   3  c
1   2  b
4   5  e
3   4  d
0   1  a
```