# Creating multiple subsets from single data frame, without replacement

Tags: python

I am trying to create 10 different subsets of 5 Members without replacement from this data (in Python):

```
      Member CIN Needs Assessment Network Enrolled
117   CS38976K                1                1
118   GN31829N                1                1
119   GD98216H                1                1
120   VJ71307A                1                1
121   OX22563R                1                1
122   YW35494W                1                1
123   QX20765B                1                1
124   NO50548K                1                1
125   VX90647K                1                1
126   RG21661H                1                1
127   IT17216C                1                1
128   LD81088I                1                1
129   UZ49716O                1                1
130   UA16736M                1                1
131   GN07797S                1                1
132   TN64827F                1                1
133   MZ23779M                1                1
134   UG76487P                1                1
135   CY90885V                1                1
136   NZ74233H                1                1
137   CB59280X                1                1
138   LI89002Q                1                1
139   LO64230I                1                1
140   NY27508Q                1                1
141   GU30027P                1                1
142   XJ75065T                1                1
143   OW40240P                1                1
144   JQ23187C                1                1
145   PQ45586F                1                1
146   IM59460P                1                1
147   OU17576V                1                1
148   KL75129O                1                1
149   XI38543M                1                1
150   PO09602E                1                1
151   PS27561N                1                1
152   PC63391R                1                1
153   WR70847S                1                1
154   XL19132L                1                1
155   ZX27683R                1                1
156   MZ63663M                1                1
157   FT35723P                1                1
158   NX90823W                1                1
159   SC16809F                1                1
160   TX83955R                1                1
161   JA79273O                1                1
162   SK66781D                1                1
163   UK69813N                1                1
164   CX01143B                1                1
165   MT45485A                1                1
166   LJ25921O                1                1
```

I tried using MANY variations of random.sample() for _ in range().
Nothing is working. Nothing so far on stack overflow seems to give me the result I need.

Comment: Hi! Exaclty, what is the result you need? Could you clarify it, please?

Comment: Hi, there are 50 members in this master data frame, I am trying to use these fake members for a rolling 10  months attribution to a program. I need to use 5 unique members monthly. So 5 unique IDs in the first subset, then 5 unique in the next...etc, from this master data frame.

Comment: The IDs should be unique only in the respective subset? In other words, the same ID can appear in two different subsets in different months?

Comment: Each ID can only appear in one subset, never repeated again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a solution using `pandas`.

Say that `master` is your master dataframe created with `pandas`, you can do:

```
shuffled = master.sample(frac=1)
```

This creates a copy of your master dataframe with rows randomly reordered. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34879805/10426037) on stackoverflow or [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) for the `sample` method.
Then you can simply build 10 smaller dataframes of five rows going in order.

```
subsets = []
for i in range(10):
    subdf = shuffled.iloc[(i*5):(i+1)*5]
    subsets.append(subdf)
```

`subsets` is the list containing your small dataframes. Do:

```
for sub in subsets:
    print(sub)
```

to print them all and verify by eye that there are not repetitions.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a combination problem. Here is a solution:
You should create your list, say L. Then you decide the size of the subset, say r. After that here is the code:

`from itertools import combinations
 combinations(L,r)`

However if you don't want to decide the size of the set to be created, then you can use random module as follows:

`import random
 from itertools import combinations
 combinations(L,r = random(a,b))`

In this case, this will create a random set of r (which is random integer between a and b) elements from the list L. If you want to do that 10 times, you can make a `for` loop.

I hope that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that we have `lines` variable with an iterator of your dataset. Then:

```
from random import sample

# Chunk length
chunk_len = 2

# Number of chunks
num_of_chunks = 5

# Get the sample with data for all chunks. It guarantees us that there will
# be no repetitions
random_sample = sample(lines, num_of_chunks*chunk_len)

# Construct the list with chunks
result = [random_sample[i::num_of_chunks] for i in range(num_of_chunks)]
result
```

Will return:

```
[['123   QX20765B                1                1',
  '118   GN31829N                1                1'],
 ['127   IT17216C                1                1',
  '122   YW35494W                1                1'],
 ['138   LI89002Q                1                1',
  '126   RG21661H                1                1'],
 ['120   VJ71307A                1                1',
  '121   OX22563R                1                1'],
 ['143   OW40240P                1                1',
  '142   XJ75065T                1                1']]
```