# How to shuffle and split a large csv with headers?

Tags: python, csv, random, header, shuffle

I am trying to find a way to shuffle the lines of a large csv files in Python and then split it into multiple csv files (assigning a number of rows for each files) but I can't manage to find a way to shuffle the large dataset, and keep the headers in each csv.
It would help a lot if someone would know how to

Here's the code I found useful for splitting a csv file:

```
number_of_rows = 100

def write_splitted_csvs(part, lines):
    with open('mycsvhere.csv'+ str(part) +'.csv', 'w') as f_out:
        f_out.write(header)
        f_out.writelines(lines)

with open("mycsvhere.csv", "r") as f:
    count = 0
    header = f.readline()
    lines = []
    for line in f:
        count += 1
        lines.append(line)
        if count % number_of_rows == 0:
            write_splitted_csvs(count // number_of_rows, lines)
            lines = []
    
    if len(lines) > 0:
        write_splitted_csvs((count // number_of_rows) + 1, lines)
```

If anyone knows how to shuffle all these splitted csv this would help a lot!
Thank you very much

Comment: you can use [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576430/shuffle-dataframe-rows) to shuffle, and also, to write it to csv.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shuffle DataFrame rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576430/shuffle-dataframe-rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using Pandas if possible.

Shuffling rows, reset the index in place:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('mycsvhere.csv'+ str(part) +'.csv')
df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then you can split into multiple dataframes into a list:

```
number_of_rows = 100
sub_dfs = [df[i:i + number_of_rows] for i in range(0, df.shape[0], number_of_rows)]
```

Then if you want to save the csvs locally:

```
for idx, sub_df in enumerate(sub_dfs):
    sub_df.to_csv(f'csv_{idx}.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: your answer is way better than mine ^^
But the OP custom dev need, does not match the mentionned "large" data, where custom devs where already made to be optimized :)

Comment: Can the OP define "large csv" please ^^ - but agree if it's large GB csv files, you may want to use another method.

Comment: Hello, I meant a datafile that could have thousands or rows but like 40MB not in GB :) so the Pandas solution works great!! Thank you very much

Comment: Great to hear - please could you mark as the correct answer if it solved your query :)

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 needs here :

- Shuffle your dataset
- Split your dataset
- Formatting

For the first 2 steps, there are some nice tools in Sklearn. You can try the stratified shuffle splitter.
[Sklearn SSS](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html)
You did not mention Stratified part, but you may need it without knowing it yet ;)

Last part, formatting, it is all up to you. You can check pandas to_csv() function where you can specify your headers, you can(need) specify your headers in the data object aswell (DataFrame). Nothing hard here, just spend a bit of time to specify what you want, and implement it easily :)

Side comments : You can drop pandas, depending on what 'big' is for you, pandas is not 'good' on big data.