# How to efficiently mix groups of columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have one dataframe in Python :

| Winner_height | Winner_rank | Loser_height | Loser_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 183 | 15 | 185 | 32 |
| 195 | 42 | 178 | 12 |

And I would like to get a mixed database keeping the information about both players and a field that allows me to identify the winner (0 if it is player 1, 1 if it is player 2), as below :

| Player_1_height | Player_1_rank | Player_2_height | Player_2_rank | Winner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 183 | 15 | 185 | 32 | 0 |
| 178 | 12 | 195 | 42 | 1 |

Is there an efficient way to mix groups of columns with pandas, i.e. without drawing a random number for each row and creating a duplicate database?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What constitutes a winner?

Comment: The information about the winner is included in the names of all the columns in the first table, and the purpose of the transformation is to dedicate a column, and no longer all the columns to this information, in order to apply a machine learning algorithm to predict the winner column

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576430/shuffle-dataframe-rows

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand how I could reuse this for my problem : here, it is not a matter of shuffling dataframe rows, but columns, or more precisely, to shuffle data with rules based on columns

Comment: If I understand, you can use `np.where`: `df2["Winner"] = np.where(df2["Player_1_height"] == df1["Winner_height"], 0, 1)`.  This will check if `winner_height` is the same as `player_1_height` and populate the `Winner` column.