# Split dataframe in 3 subgroups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to split raw dataframe into 3 subgroups: train, test, validate

I see three solutions, but afraid they are not correct and may cause bottle neck effect

1) add dictionary with keys

```
my_dict = {'train':raw_df.loc[start:end], 'test':raw_df.loc[start:end],
            'val':raw_df.loc[start:end]}
```

2) create three dataframes

```
train_df = df.loc[start:end]
test_df = df.loc[start:end]
val_df = df.loc[start:end]
```

3) add new column with one of three random values random

```
df['train/test/val'] = pd.Series('train', index=df.index)
```

ALso, will adding dataframe in dictionary cause: bottle_neck effect of loosing performance advantages of dataframe being help in dictionary or list?
Adding new columns in theory is increasing dimension of data
Creating new dataframes I think is the worst variant cause it will eat tons of memory

Comment: Adding a new column will not increase the dimension as you will not include it in a learning process. If you are worried about the space (though I don't think it will take much space) you can just store the cutpoints (i.e. 0, 25, 70, 100) and when needed use the slices of the dataframe (df[0:25], df[25:70] etc). Dividing them into three different dataframes will also not increase the memory usage much.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a new column won't be eating lots of memorys but you will add a slicing cost whenever you want to access one of your three sets. Creating new datraframes leads this slicing part to be done only once.

For this you can use `sample`. Let's you want 80% of your dataframe in train, and 10% in test and validate:

```
train = df.sample(frac = 0.8)
test = df.drop(train.index).sample(frac = 0.5)
validate = df.drop(train.index).drop(test.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, i don't think you need to have three dataframes if you want to test your machine learning model. Why? Because you build you model on your `training_set` and you need to validate it with your `validation_set`. You will only use your `test_set` once your model is validated. Also, your `test_set` doesn't contain the `Y` label.

Several libraries contain functions to split your data easily.

- `scikit-learn` gives you the option to use `train_test_split` http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html
- `spark-ml` has `randomSplit`
- ...

Without using any external library you can do this:

```
msk = np.random.rand(len(df)) < 0.8
train = df[msk]
validation = df[~msk]
```

(answer from: [How do I create test and train samples from one dataframe with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147278/how-do-i-create-test-and-train-samples-from-one-dataframe-with-pandas))

Hope this helps!

Comment: The train/test/validate is a way of splitting used for instance in kaggle's competitions. Want you train on this kind of plateformes, it can be useful to split your data in three sets. As for the rest of the time, I totally agree with you.

Comment: @ysearka I checked out Kaggle some time ago, do you know why they would want three splits?

Comment: You can use `train`/`test` to cross-validate your model, and keep a `validate` set (which can be common with other people) to compare your results. Which permits to have an objective comparison on the same set.

Answer (score 0):

A pure pandas solution for only a single iteration would be to use sample, and exclude the index of your sample for your next iteration with `pd.Index.difference`:

```
validation = df.sample(validation_size)
# Get the other part of the dataframe
train_test = df.loc[df.index.difference(validation.index)]

test = train_test.sample(test_size)
train = train_test.loc[train_test.index.difference(test.index)]
```

Note that `validation_size` and `test_size` are the number of rows you want for your validation and test frames, respectively.

Sklearn also has great functionality for doing splits in a loop for easier cross validation. Documentation here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.ShuffleSplit.html

Comment: just saw ysearka's answer and upvoted, it's better than mine.