# Stratified splitting of pandas dataframe into training, validation and test set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, sampling

The following extremely simplified DataFrame represents a much larger DataFrame containing medical diagnoses:

```
medicalData = pd.DataFrame({'diagnosis':['positive','positive','negative','negative','positive','negative','negative','negative','negative','negative']})
medicalData

    diagnosis
0   positive
1   positive
2   negative
3   negative
4   positive
5   negative
6   negative
7   negative
8   negative
9   negative
```

Problem: For machine learning, **I need to randomly split this dataframe into three subframes** in the following way:

```
trainingDF, validationDF, testDF = SplitData(medicalData,fractions = [0.6,0.2,0.2])
```

...where the split array specifies the fraction of the complete data that goes into each subframe.

- the data in the subframe needs to be **mutually exclusive** and the split array (fractions) need to sum to one.
- **Aditionally, the fraction of positive diagnoses in each subset needs to be approximately the same.**
- [Answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147278/how-do-i-create-test-and-train-samples-from-one-dataframe-with-pandas)  recommend using [the pandas sample method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) or [the train_test_split function from sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). But none of these solutions seem to generalize well to n splits and none provides a stratified split.

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24151789/4909087

Comment: You know you could just split the test into two parts again.

Comment: Thanks, but I have explicitely mentioned in my question that these solutions dont cover my second requirement, that each subset needs to approximately contain the same fraction of positive samples.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### `np.array_split`

If you want to generalise to `n` splits, `np.array_split` is your friend (it works with DataFrames well).

```
fractions = np.array([0.6, 0.2, 0.2])
# shuffle your input
df = df.sample(frac=1) 
# split into 3 parts
train, val, test = np.array_split(
    df, (fractions[:-1].cumsum() * len(df)).astype(int))
```

---

#### `train_test_split`

A windy solution using [`train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html#sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split) for stratified splitting.

```
y = df.pop('diagnosis').to_frame()
X = df
```

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        X, y,stratify=y, test_size=0.4)

X_test, X_val, y_test, y_val = train_test_split(
        X_test, y_test, stratify=y_test, test_size=0.5)
```

Where `X` is a DataFrame of your features, and `y` is a single-columned DataFrame of your labels.

Comment: Thanks, that covers my first requirement. But what about my second requirement that each subset needs to approximately contain the same fraction of positive samples?

Comment: @user1934212 assuming you have an equal number of samples and enough data, it should be fine (thanks to randomness). But if you're particular on that stuff, I don't think you can work with this. Maybe look into StratifiedKFold splitting with sklearn.

Comment: The nature of medical data is, that there are usually much less positive diagnosis than negative diagnosis. At least in my case  #positive/#negative == 20/80

Comment: can I just pass the dataframe into train_test_split? Or what are the parameters X and y based on my code sample?

Comment: @user1934212 y is your column of labels, and X is every column that does not include y.

Comment: @user1934212 One last thing, please ensure y has a shape of `[xxx, 1]`.

Comment: I dont understand your last comment. Could you improve your answer such that it uses the dataFrame object I use in my question?

Comment: Many more, but I left the others out in my example for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172833/discussion-between-user1934212-and-coldspeed).

Comment: @user1934212 I'm not going to be active, so if you have any followups I'd recommend opening a new question :)

Comment: @cs95: You use `df.pop()` to remove the dataframe column that has the y label. What if I want to keep the y label with the dataframe? Would you remove the `pop()` and just do `y = df['diagnosis'].to_frame()`?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 `df[ ['diagnosis'] ]` pass a list of columns, it's easier.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a Python function that splits a Pandas dataframe into train, validation, and test dataframes with ***stratified sampling***. It performs this split by calling scikit-learn's function `train_test_split()` twice.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def split_stratified_into_train_val_test(df_input, stratify_colname='y',
                                         frac_train=0.6, frac_val=0.15, frac_test=0.25,
                                         random_state=None):
    '''
    Splits a Pandas dataframe into three subsets (train, val, and test)
    following fractional ratios provided by the user, where each subset is
    stratified by the values in a specific column (that is, each subset has
    the same relative frequency of the values in the column). It performs this
    splitting by running train_test_split() twice.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df_input : Pandas dataframe
        Input dataframe to be split.
    stratify_colname : str
        The name of the column that will be used for stratification. Usually
        this column would be for the label.
    frac_train : float
    frac_val   : float
    frac_test  : float
        The ratios with which the dataframe will be split into train, val, and
        test data. The values should be expressed as float fractions and should
        sum to 1.0.
    random_state : int, None, or RandomStateInstance
        Value to be passed to train_test_split().

    Returns
    -------
    df_train, df_val, df_test :
        Dataframes containing the three splits.
    '''

    if frac_train + frac_val + frac_test != 1.0:
        raise ValueError('fractions %f, %f, %f do not add up to 1.0' % \
                         (frac_train, frac_val, frac_test))

    if stratify_colname not in df_input.columns:
        raise ValueError('%s is not a column in the dataframe' % (stratify_colname))

    X = df_input # Contains all columns.
    y = df_input[[stratify_colname]] # Dataframe of just the column on which to stratify.

    # Split original dataframe into train and temp dataframes.
    df_train, df_temp, y_train, y_temp = train_test_split(X,
                                                          y,
                                                          stratify=y,
                                                          test_size=(1.0 - frac_train),
                                                          random_state=random_state)

    # Split the temp dataframe into val and test dataframes.
    relative_frac_test = frac_test / (frac_val + frac_test)
    df_val, df_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(df_temp,
                                                      y_temp,
                                                      stratify=y_temp,
                                                      test_size=relative_frac_test,
                                                      random_state=random_state)

    assert len(df_input) == len(df_train) + len(df_val) + len(df_test)

    return df_train, df_val, df_test
```

Below is a complete working example.

Consider a dataset that has a label upon which you want to perform the stratification. This label has its own distribution in the original dataset, say 75% `foo`, 15% `bar` and 10% `baz`. Now let's split the dataset into train, validation, and test into subsets using a 60/20/20 ratio, where each split retains the same distribution of the labels. See the illustration below:

[image]

Here is the example dataset:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame( { 'A': list(range(0, 100)),
                     'B': list(range(100, 0, -1)),
                     'label': ['foo'] * 75 + ['bar'] * 15 + ['baz'] * 10 } )

df.head()
#    A    B label
# 0  0  100   foo
# 1  1   99   foo
# 2  2   98   foo
# 3  3   97   foo
# 4  4   96   foo

df.shape
# (100, 3)

df.label.value_counts()
# foo    75
# bar    15
# baz    10
# Name: label, dtype: int64
```

Now, let's call the `split_stratified_into_train_val_test()` function from above to get train, validation, and test dataframes following a 60/20/20 ratio.

```py
df_train, df_val, df_test = \
    split_stratified_into_train_val_test(df, stratify_colname='label', frac_train=0.60, frac_val=0.20, frac_test=0.20)
```

The three dataframes `df_train`, `df_val`, and `df_test` contain all the original rows but their sizes will follow the above ratio.

```py
df_train.shape
#(60, 3)

df_val.shape
#(20, 3)

df_test.shape
#(20, 3)
```

Further, each of the three splits will have the same distribution of the label, namely 75% `foo`, 15% `bar` and 10% `baz`.

```py
df_train.label.value_counts()
# foo    45
# bar     9
# baz     6
# Name: label, dtype: int64

df_val.label.value_counts()
# foo    15
# bar     3
# baz     2
# Name: label, dtype: int64

df_test.label.value_counts()
# foo    15
# bar     3
# baz     2
# Name: label, dtype: int64
```

Comment: this function returns the following error
ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2.
value_counts()
Skyra_0      105
Skyra_2       37
Skyra_1       29
Skyra_3       18
TrioTim_4      7
Skyra_4        5
TrioTim_2      5
TrioTim_5      5
Skyra_5        5
TrioTim_3      3

Answer (score 0):

To @stackoverflowuser2010 answer I added a dictionary for assigning manual ratios for the less frequent labels (<10) that gave an error with the function {amount_of_examples: [train_length, val, test]}. Here is the outcome:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
def split_stratified_into_train_val_test(df_input, stratify_tuples_colname='y',
                                         frac_train=0.6, frac_val=0.15, frac_test=0.25,
                                         random_state=None,
                                         ratio_dict = {3: [1,1,1], 4: [2,1,1], 5: [2,2,1], 
6: [2,2,2], 7: [3,2,2], 8: [4,2,2], 9: [5,2,2]}
                                         ):
    '''
    Splits a Pandas dataframe into three subsets (train, val, and test)
    following fractional ratios provided by the user, where each subset is
    stratified by the values in a specific column (that is, each subset has
    the same relative frequency of the values in the column). It performs this
    splitting by running train_test_split() twice.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df_input : Pandas dataframe
        Input dataframe to be split.
    stratify_colname : str
        The name of the column that will be used for stratification. Usually
        this column would be for the label.
    frac_train : float
    frac_val   : float
    frac_test  : float
        The ratios with which the dataframe will be split into train, val, and
        test data. The values should be expressed as float fractions and should
        sum to 1.0.
    random_state : int, None, or RandomStateInstance
        Value to be passed to train_test_split()
ratio_dict : dict
dict for manual ratio {amount_of_examples: [train_length, dev, test]}

    Returns
    -------
    df_train, df_val, df_test :
        Dataframes containing the three splits.
    '''
    
    #checks
    if frac_train + frac_val + frac_test != 1.0:
        raise ValueError('fractions %f, %f, %f do not add up to 1.0' % \
                         (frac_train, frac_val, frac_test))

    if stratify_tuples_colname not in df_input.columns:
        raise ValueError('%s is not a column in the dataframe' % (stratify_tuples_colname))
    
    #create freq_dict
    label_freq_dict = df[stratify_tuples_colname].value_counts().to_dict()
    #Those with less than 10 occurances are too little for train_test_split logic.
    # Take out to deal with them later
    df_input["is_frequent_enough"] = df_input[stratify_tuples_colname].apply(lambda x: True if label_freq_dict[x] >= 10 else False)
    rare_labels_df = df_input.query('is_frequent_enough == False', engine='python')
    df_input = df_input.drop(rare_labels_df.index)

    X = df_input # Contains all columns.
    y = df_input[[stratify_tuples_colname]] # Dataframe of just the column on which to stratify.

    # Split original dataframe into train and temp dataframes.
    df_train, df_temp, y_train, y_temp = train_test_split(X,
                                                          y,
                                                          stratify=y,
                                                          test_size=(1.0 - frac_train),
                                                          random_state=random_state)

    # Split the temp dataframe into val and test dataframes.
    relative_frac_test = frac_test / (frac_val + frac_test)
    df_val, df_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(df_temp,
                                                      y_temp,
                                                      stratify=y_temp,
                                                      test_size=relative_frac_test,
                                                      random_state=random_state)
    
    #Add rare_labels_df into the sets manually
    rare_labels = rare_labels_df[stratify_tuples_colname].unique()
    
    for rare_label in rare_labels:
        mini_df = rare_labels_df[rare_labels_df[stratify_tuples_colname] == rare_label].copy()
        mini_df_len = len(mini_df)
        if mini_df_len <= 2: #If not 1 example for every set, then exclude
            continue
        dev_test = mini_df.tail(ratio_dict[len(mini_df)][1]+ ratio_dict[len(mini_df)][2])
        train = mini_df.drop(dev_test.index)
        test = dev_test.tail(ratio_dict[len(mini_df)][2])
        dev = dev_test.drop(test.index)
        assert mini_df_len == len(train) + len(dev) + len(test)
        df_val = pd.concat([df_val, dev])
        df_train = pd.concat([df_train, train])
        df_test = pd.concat([df_test, test])

    #assert len(df_input)+len(rare_labels_df) == len(df_train) + len(df_val) + len(df_test)

    return df_train, df_val, df_test
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Pure `pandas` solution

To split into train / validation / test in the ratio 70 / 20 / 10%:

```
train_df = df.sample(frac=0.7, random_state=random_seed)
tmp_df = df.drop(train_df.index)
test_df = tmp_df.sample(frac=0.33333, random_state=random_seed)
valid_df = tmp_df.drop(test_df.index)

assert len(df) == len(train_df) + len(valid_df) + len(test_df), "Dataset sizes don't add up"
del tmp_df
```

Comment: This doesn't get at the OP request of stratified splits.