# I have a csv file and want to extract a column and strore int as array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a csv file. One of its column name is mpg. I am reading file in  this way.

```
data = pd.read_csv('auto-mpg.csv')   
var_1 = data['mpg']  
train_y = numpy.asarray(var_1)
```

How can I copy the data of var1 data into `train_y` array?

Comment: Whats the type of your mpg column?

Answer (score 0):

New: OK Missed that it was a training array, this likely is the same question,
[How do I create test and train samples from one dataframe with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147278/how-do-i-create-test-and-train-samples-from-one-dataframe-with-pandas)

Old:
Some sample data would help, but you can use pandas to rip and format the data on the first pass. this is what I imagine you expect it to work like.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy

    df = pd.read_csv('auto-mpg.csv',converters={"mpg": lambda x: numpy.asarray(x)})
    train_y = df.mpg
```