# Why a dataframe return an array of numerical values when the index array of boolean value?

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning how to training and test sample by a dataframe.
I review a [solution post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147278/how-do-i-create-test-and-train-samples-from-one-dataframe-with-pandas), but I can not understand some detail on code syntax .

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 2))

In [12]: msk = np.random.rand(len(df)) < 0.8

In [13]: train = df[msk]

In [14]: test = df[~msk]

In [15]: len(test)
Out[15]: 21

In [16]: len(train)
Out[16]: 79
```

Since msk will return an array of boolean. How can the msk be index of df and df[msk] return the actual numerical data? From my understanding, the index of df should be one string or an array of string.

Comment: This is a purely `pandas` question, and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `linear-regression` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Pandas documentation on [boolean indexing](http://tps://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

> You may select rows from a DataFrame using a boolean vector the same
>   length as the DataFrame’s index

In your example by using `df[msk]` you get the lines in `df` that have the same indexes of the `True` values in the boolean vector `msk`, with `df[~msk]` those corresponding to the `False` values in `msk`.

Answer (score 0):

In NumPy and Pandas, an array of booleans which is the same length as the array you're indexing is treated as a "mask," and selects the values where the mask is True.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
import numpy as np
print(temp == 1)

Output:
[ True  True  True False False False]
```

Every element in temp is checked if it is equal to "1" and the boolean list is returned the same. What you are doing is just the opposite of this.

This is only possible with numpy. Python list will not support Boolean indexing. And applying the same on the python native list give "False" in return as this will compare the number to the whole list.