# Shuffling training data before splitting using Keras DataGenerator

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

My model is pretty obviously overfitting and I keep seeing everywhere that I should try shuffling my data before splitting it. I use:
[image]

to do my data processing and splitting right now and learned that the shuffle=True doesn't actually do what I thought it did (or possibly anything). So my question is how should I load in and split this data? I have image files in a train folder and then I have a .csv file with the file name in one column and the label in the other column. This is my first attempt at any machine learning stuff so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: I understand that this is now your question but you may want to look at https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit if you have issues with overfitting.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, you are loading `dataframe=df` as input for your training/ validation set and `dataframe=test_df` for your test set. `shuffle=True` will shuffle the loaded samples within the specified dataframe.

So if you load from different sources, you are shuffling *after* splitting.

To shuffle before splitting, you need to either

- shuffle the images between directories before loading or
- load it with ImageDataGenerator (shuffle=True), split it with array operations and manually set y_col and batch_size for your test set or
- remove different directories for your files altogether, load your .csv as a Pandas DataFrame, [shuffle and split the rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147278/how-do-i-create-test-and-train-samples-from-one-dataframe-with-pandas) and then use those partial dataframes as input for your ImageDataGenerators

Personally, I would choose the last option.