# Assigning different Dataframes to different variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am creating test and training data for an algorithm. I have data in different csv files I want to create training and test data from that.

I have imported all the csv files to the pandas dataframe using

```py
dfs = [pd.read_csv(file) for file in datafiles]
```

dfs[1] has the first dataframe dfs[2] second and so on

I would like to assign them to different data frame in the format Xtest1 is dfs[1], Xtest2 is dfs[2] and so on till the end of the files

Can anyone help do it using a loop or any other idea

Comment: Are you using sklearn? They have a function to do this for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create test and train samples from one dataframe with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147278/how-do-i-create-test-and-train-samples-from-one-dataframe-with-pandas)

Comment: Why flood global environment with many similar objects and not just keep using the **one** list you have?

Comment: See [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a dictionary to do this. Can you try the following:

```
dfs = {'Xtest'+ str(ind): pd.read_csv(file) for ind, file in enumerate(datafiles)}
```

And whenever you need to access the dataframe, you can do it the following way:

```
dfs['Xtest1']
```

If you want to iterate the dictionary you can do using the following:

```
for i in range(4):
    print(dfs['Xtest' + str(i)])
```

Comment: Hi Jeril thanks alot. Actually i have to apply a train test split function for that i need the dataframe in separate dataframe like X_test1, X_test2. is there any way i can iterate like a for loop in which I can change variables like Xtest# and # can be a number like 1 2 3 depending on the loop iteration number.

Comment: `dfs` is a dictionary of dataframes, and you can iterate it in a forloop. Check my revised solution.

Comment: Hi Jeril. Thanks. Actually I have to do the following. I want to do it in a loop 

train1, test1 = train_test_split(training_set1, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)
train2, test2 = train_test_split(training_set2, test_size=0.4, shuffle=False)
train3, test3 = train_test_split(training_set3, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)

for i in range(10, len(train1)):
    X_train1.append(train1[i-10:i, 1:11])
    y_train1.append(train1[i, 10])
X_train1, y_train1 = np.array(X_train1), np.array(y_train1)

similarly for train2 and train 3

Answer (score 0):

You mean automatically create variables and assign something to them?

try globals(), locals()

i.e.

```
for a in range(10):
    locals()["var1_"+str(a)+"] = 1
```