# How to use the fraction of training dataset in the testing dataset

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm recently studying neural network and panda dataframe, the dataset that I have is split into several .csv files, and for the train dataset I load them as follows:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("/home/path/to/file/data1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("/home/path/to/file/data2.csv")
df3 = pd.read_csv("/home/path/to/file/data3.csv")
df4 = pd.read_csv("/home/path/to/file/data4.csv")
df5 = pd.read_csv("/home/path/to/file/data5.csv")

trainDataset = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4, df5])
```

Then, as suggested by many articles, the test dataset should be around 20% of the train dataset. My questions are:

1. How can I define the test dataset to be 20% of the train dataset?
2. When I load both train and test dataset, what is the best way to randomize the data?

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147278/how-do-i-create-test-and-train-samples-from-one-dataframe-with-pandas), and wrote the following code but it didn't work:

```
testDataset = train_test_split(trainDataset, test_size=0.2)
```

I appreciate any tips or help for this matter.

Comment: Can you please show us the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `train_test_split` would give you the answer, but I'm a bit surprised by the call you had in your example.

It is more common to have something like this, with `x` being the features (the `x` in `y=f(x)`, with `f` is the real function that you try to mimic with your learning) and `y` being the responses (the `y` in `y=f(x)`).

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
```

For more explanations, please see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation

Comment: No `y` is not needed in the `train_test_split`. The why OP is using is valid. The problem  is not the way he is using.

Comment: `train_test_split(data,  test_size=0.2, random_state=42)` add `random_state` for fixed random shuffling

Comment: this will randomize the test dataset, is it possible to randomize the train dataset as well?

Comment: @mujjiga indeed, but that’s easier to understand that way, given obviously the hypothesis that this is supervised learning

Comment: @saadh17 It creates a dedicated test and training set. If you have another test set, you can use it for cross validation, for example to compare different learnings (algo, hyper parameters, etc)

Comment: Regarding the random_state, it depends if you want to have exactly the same selection (reproducible research) or not.

Comment: Given the fact that it is randomization, I think it is more honest to keep it “out of control “ ... otherwise good results might be due to an (improbable) set of lucky situations. If you keep it random, you only rely on the quality of the learning algorithm, and not a lucky set of examples. Also, repeating it with pure randomness can give an idea of the variance of the evaluation.