# How to get `train_test_split` to work with a dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, xgboost

I have a complex data frame with 10,999 rows.

I am trying to run xgboost for machine learning.

I load in the data and attempt to split it as I see in tutorials and by solutions posted on StackOverflow: [How do I create test and train samples from one dataframe with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147278/how-do-i-create-test-and-train-samples-from-one-dataframe-with-pandas)

```
X_train, X_test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2)
```

but this fails:

```
TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
```

But this doesn't make sense, how can I possibly put a dataframe into an array without losing lots of valuable information?

so I was advised to try pandas:

```
pandasDF = df.toPandas
X_train, X_test = train_test_split(pandasDF, test_size=0.2)
```

but this also fails:

```
TypeError: Singleton array array(<bound method PandasConversionMixin.toPandas of DataFrame
```

how can I split this dataframe into training and test sets?

Comment: Could it be that the only error is that you forgot the method call? So use `pandasDF = df.toPandas()` instead?

Comment: indeed, I used attribute instead of method :( now it works @VirtualScooter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this option:

```
pandasDF = df.toPandas()
```

If its taking time use this configuration before the conversion

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
```

Comment: the key point was that I screwed up, and used the attribute instead of the method