# How to randomly segment lines from one text file into two different text files?

Tags: python, random

I have a text file with say, 100 lines, I want to randomly segment these lines into 80-20 lines into two separate text files, Using the code below but it's not doing proper partition. I am getting a different number of files. I should get 80 lines in file2 and 20 files in file1.

Can someone point out the error and suggest if there is a better way. Please note in total.txt is the original file which needs to be segmented into file1 and file 2.

```
def partition(l, pred):
    fid_train=open('meta/file1.txt','w')
    fid_test = open('meta/file2.txt','w')
    for e in l:
        if pred(e):
            fid_test.write(e)
        else:
            #fid_train.write(e+'\n')
            fid_train.write(e)
    return fid_train,fid_test

lines = open("meta/total_list.txt").readlines()
lines1, lines2 = partition(lines, lambda x: random.random() < 0.2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you only have 100 lines and you apparently want an exact 80/20 split, I'd suggest just shuffling and writing out the number of lines you want.  Something like:

```
import random

# read everything in
lines = open("meta/total_list.txt").readlines()

# randomise order
random.shuffle(lines)

# split array up and write out according to desired proportions
open('meta/file1.txt', 'w').writelines(lines[:20])
open('meta/file2.txt', 'w').writelines(lines[20:])
```

Note that many libraries provide similar functionality, e.g. [scikit-learn provides `train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).

Your original way you were doing it would result in a [binomial draw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), and would likely give you between 12 and 28 lines in file1.  You can calculate this analytically via:

```
from scipy.stats import binom

binom.ppf([0.025, 0.975], 100, 0.2)
```

Comment: its not working for me, I don't know why for text files its throwing an error: 'list' object has no attribute 'shuffle'   The total_list is a text file, so I am using 'lines = open("meta/total_list.txt").readlines()
lines.shuffle()'

Comment: @KRISHNACHAUHAN sorry, I misremembered where the shuffle method lives, have updated the answer using the random module

Comment: Thank you so much sir, @Sam Mason, I wish I could learn to use train_test_split in this situation incase of text files.

Comment: @KRISHNACHAUHAN see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55442136/1358308  in your case you can just do: `file1, file2 = train_test_split(lines, test_size=0.2)` and you'll get lists of the appropriate length in `file1` and `file2`

Comment: sir I have done this before but my dataloader is reading files location from these train test text files only. and here I am getting lists, is there any way to write into text files using this function

Comment: erm, using `open(...).writelines(...)` as normal...