# Having problems with splitting a dataframe into train and test

Tags: python, pandas

I am splitting a data frame into test and train dataframes but have a problem with the output.I want to et the dataframes for train and test The code is as follows.

```
train_prices=int(len(prices)*0.65)
test_prices=len(prices)-train_prices
train_data,test_data=prices.iloc[0:train_prices,:].values,prices.iloc[train_prices:len(prices),:1].values
```

however, I only get a single value rather than dataframes.The output is something of the sort
code

```
training_size,test_size
```

Output

```
11156746, 813724
```

I expect train and test dataframes that will enable me to go on with ML models.

Please assist

Comment: Your code looks reasonable.  You should provide a [mcve] in order for us to more easily help you solve your problem.

Comment: @piRSquared, edited. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: a [mcve] includes an actual sample dataset such that I can run the sample myself.  See, the problem is I have no idea what `prices` is and that could be the problem.  But I can't know that unless you show me exactly how `prices` was created.  That said, your probably better off reading these answers [https://stackoverflow.com/q/24147278/2336654] or [https://stackoverflow.com/q/38250710/2336654]

Answer (score 1):

since you didn't provide any reproducible example, I'll demonstrate on iris dataset.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
data = load_iris(as_frame=True)
data = data["data"]
data.head()
```

```
    sepal length (cm)   sepal width (cm)    petal length (cm)   petal width (cm)
0   5.1                 3.5                 1.4                 0.2
1   4.9                 3.0                 1.4                 0.2
2   4.7                 3.2                 1.3                 0.2
3   4.6                 3.1                 1.5                 0.2
4   5.0                 3.6                 1.4                 0.2
```

first, remove the `.values` from your code. [values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) gives you the values as a list, but you want the output to be dataframe.

second, in test_data you took only the first column, since you used `prices.iloc[train_prices:len(prices),:1]` instead of
`prices.iloc[train_prices:len(prices),:]` as you did in train_data.

so in order to get two dataframe outputs for train and test:

```
train_prices=int(len(data)*0.65)
test_prices=len(data)-train_prices
train_data,test_data=data.iloc[0:train_prices,:],data.iloc[train_prices:len(data),:]
```

btw, if you want to do some ML, check out sklearn [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) method.