# Dataset splitting with pandas sample and drop does not work as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have a train dataset with 4,000 examples, I want to split it randomly into 2 equal sub-datasets with 2,000 in each of them. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147278/how-do-i-create-test-and-train-samples-from-one-dataframe-with-pandas) i used the `split` and `drop` methods like so:

```py
I1 = train_df.sample(frac=0.5, random_state=opts.seed)
I2 = train_df.drop(index=I1.index)
```

However it seems like it drops more indices for no apparent reason:

```
print(len(train_df))
print(len(I1))
print(len(I2))

4000
2000
1010
```

I would appreciate any insight as to why it happens.

Comment: Try to `reset_index()` maybe ?

Comment: @ErnestBidouille Yea now it works, thanks! I wonder why it would do any difference though, I initialize the dataset just before..

Comment: Btw feel free to write it as an answer and i'll accept it :)

Comment: Sometimes, indexing is a bit sensitive with pandas ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it's just that `train_df` has multiple same indexes. This should work as expected:

```py
train_df = train_df.reset_index(drop=True)
I1 = train_df.sample(frac=0.5, random_state=opts.seed)
I2 = train_df.drop(index=I1.index)
```