# Convert pandas series into numpy array

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I am new to pandas and python. My input data is like

```
category   text
1   hello iam fine. how are you
1   iam good. how are you doing.

inputData= pd.read_csv(Input', sep='\t', names=['category','text'])
X = inputData["text"]
Y = inputData["category"]
```

here Y is the panda series object, which i want to convert into numpy array. so i tried .as_matrix

```
YArray= Y.as_matrix(columns=None)
print YArray
```

But i got the output as [1,1] (which is wrong since i have only one column category and two rows). I want the result as 2x1 matrix.

Comment: `.values` wil be shunned in favour of two new methods starting v0.24.0. See [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54324513/4909087)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:
after applying the .as_matrix on your series object

```
Y.reshape((2,1))
```

Since .as_matrix() only returns a numpy-array NOT a numpy-matrix.
[Link here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html)

Comment: reshape is deprecated

use Y.values.reshape(2,1) instead.

Answer (score 88):

To get numpy array, you need

```
Y.values
```

Comment: when i do Y.values(), it throws, TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: @vishnu It's a property, not a method.

Comment: thanks. but reshape worked for me!

Comment: @vishnu  Not sure the original post is updated based on your comment, but the way is to do Y.values, not Y.values().

Answer (score 13):

If df is your dataframe, then a column of the dataframe is a series and to convert it into an array,

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
x = df.values
print(x.type)
```

The following prints,

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

successfully converting it to an array.