# Return first column in DataFrame as a list of string values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how can I return a list of string values for first column (State) from below DataFrame?

```
                             Population
State       County  
California  Los Angeles County  9818605
Illinois    Cook County         5194675
Texas       Harris County       4092459
```

Comment: `print (df.index.get_level_values('State'))` - it is dupe :(

Comment: I am receiving:NameError: name 'index' is not defined

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29774704/2901002)

Comment: Hmm, what about `print (df.index.get_level_values(0))` ?

Comment: So sorry, first solution already worked but I had a data error. Many thanks for quick reply!! How can I convert it to a list of string values?

Comment: use `print (df.index.get_level_values('State').tolist())` ?

Answer (score 0):

last bit is solved: converting index to list with:
df.index.get_level_values(0).tolist()

Many thanks for your help!
Peter