# Plotly Bar Chart Based on Pandas dataframe grouped by year

Tags: pandas, plotly

I have a pandas dataframe that I've tried to group by year on 'Close Date' and then plot 'ARR (USD)' on the y-axis against the year on the x-axis.

All seems fine after grouping:

```
sumyr = brandarr.groupby(brandarr['Close Date'].dt.year,as_index=True).sum()

         ARR (USD)
Close Date  
2017    17121174.33
2018    15383130.32
```

But when I try to plot:

```
trace = [go.Bar(
x=sumyr['Close Date'],
y=sumyr['ARR (USD)']
)]
```

I get the error: KeyError: 'Close Date'

I'm sure it's something stupid, I'm a newbie, but I've been messing with it for an hour and well, here I am. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your groupby function you have used `as_index=True` so `Close Date` is now an *index*. If you want to have access to an index, use pandas `.loc` or `.iloc`.
To have access to the index values directly, use:

```
sumyr.index.tolist()
```

Check here: [Pandas - how to get the data frame index as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241004/pandas-how-to-get-the-data-frame-index-as-an-array)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much!